# Methods with the same name in one class in Python

Tags: python, overloading

How can I declare a few methods with the same name, but with different numbers of parameters or different types in one class?

What must I change in the following class?

```
class MyClass:
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
    def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String):
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String

    def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String,parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String):
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String
        print parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String

    def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int):
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String * parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int
```

Comment: you may want to read this. http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html and this http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/java-is-not-python-either.html

Comment: After experimenting with this for a little while, I have found that it appears to be valid to write multiple functions with the same name in Python, but that each time you write another function with the same name, the interpreter completely forgets about the prior functions with that name.

Comment: Related: [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

Comment: @TomWillis I think the titles you linked should say "Python is not an OOP language."  Polymorphism is not a Java concept. It is one of the 4~5 core principles of OOP. There was a time when these were considered the minimum api that a language needed to expose in order to call itself object oriented. Half-implemented feature sets are just asking for anti-patterns via forced workarounds. I still love the language. It just needs to pick a lane and hold the wheel steady.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can have a function that takes in a variable number of arguments.

```
def my_method(*args, **kwds):
    # Do something

# When you call the method
my_method(a1, a2, k1=a3, k2=a4)

# You get:
args = (a1, a2)
kwds = {'k1':a3, 'k2':a4}
```

So you can modify your function as follows:

```
def my_method(*args):
    if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], str):
        # Case 1
    elif len(args) == 2 and isinstance(args[1], int):
        # Case 2
    elif len(args) == 2 and isinstance(args[1], str):
        # Case 3
```

Comment: This is the right way of doing this, except that you should raise an exception in the failsafe case. Something like `else: raise TypeError('Parameter 1 should be a string and parameter 2 should be a string, int or omitted entirely')`. And, as @delnan says, use `basestring` instead of `str` unless you have a good reason for not wanting unicode.

Comment: Thanks! I'm years late, but this solves my headache about different signatures for same method (child class to override parent class).

Comment: As of Python 3.10 a more elegant solution would be to use Structural Pattern Matching. You can find my implementation below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74745600/4508848

Answer (score 33):

You can't. There are not overloads or multimethods or similar things. One name refers to one thing. As far as the language is concerned anyway, you can always emulate them yourself... You *could* check types with `isinstance` (but please do it properly - e.g. in Python 2, use `basestring` to detect both strings and unicode), but it's ugly, generally discouraged and rarely useful. If the methods do different things, give them different names. Consider polymorphism as well.

Comment: If you consider polymorphism in python then ur back at using isinstance() and other type() checking, no? How do you mean polymorphism in python?

Comment: @RetroCode I mean polymorphism as in object-oriented programming, i.e., a bunch of classes (probably with some inheriting from others, but not necessarily in Python due to duck typing) that have methods of the same name with compatible signatures.

Comment: I do not feel any need to do something like: get_user_by_id(id) and get_user_by_name(name) when I could just do get_user(id) and get_user(name) overload. The parameter list is there to distinguish the two, it's clear and concise. Without overloading you can get ridiculous function names. I hope Python adds overloading in future.

Answer (score 27):

Using Python 3.5 or higher, you can use `@typing.overload` to provide type annotations for overloaded functions/methods.

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload):

```py
@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    <actual implementation>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, `from typing import overload` is required.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: you can't ([see this previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733264/function-overloading-in-python-missing)). Typically you'd use something like (you could add more type checking and reorder):

```
def my_method(self,parameter_A, parameter_B=None):
  if isinstance(parameter_B, int):
    print parameter_A * parameter_B
  else:
    print parameter_A
    if parameter_B is not None:
      print parameter_B
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try multimethods in Python:

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605

But I don't believe multimethod is a way to go. Rather objects that you pass to a method should have common interface. You are trying to achieve method overloading similar to the one in C++, but it is very rarely required in Python. One way to do this is a cascade of `ifs` using `isinstance`, but that's ugly.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO (and the only real solution). A package is available https://pypi.org/project/multimethod/.

Answer (score 2):

Python is nothing like Java.

There are not really types, just objects with methods.

There is a way to test if a passed object is from a class, but it is mainly bad practices.

However, the code you want to produce for the two first methods should be something like

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self, str1, str2=None):
        print str1
        if str2: print str2
```

For the third, well... Use a different name...

Comment: (1) There are types, you just don't set the types of names in stone via static typing. (2) `if x` is a horrible way to check for `None`. It really checks if `x` is "falsy". (3) Optional parameters don't really work for the example, nor for overloading in general.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work. No matter how many arguments you have, the name `m` will be overriden with the second `m` method.

```
class C:
    def m(self):
        print('m first')
    def m(self, x):
        print(f'm second {x}')


ci=C();
#ci.m() # will not work TypeError: m() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
ci.m(1) # works
```

---

The output will simple be:

```
m second 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.10 a more elegant solution would be to use [Structural Pattern Matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/).

```py
def my_method(parameters):
    match parameters:
        case str():
            # Case 1
        case (str(), str()):
            # Case 2
        case (str(), int()):
            # Case 3
        case _:
            print('no match')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a pattern similar to the following:
Note that adding '_' to the beginning of a method name is convention for marking a private method.

```
class MyClass:
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
    def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String, param2=None):
        if type(param2) == str:
            return self._my_method_extra_string_version(parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String, param2)
        elif type(param2) == int:
            return self._my_method_extra_int_version(parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String, param2)
        else:
            pass # use the default behavior in this function
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String

    def _my_method_extra_string_version(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String, parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String):
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String
        print parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String

    def _my_method_extra_int_version(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String, parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int):
        print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String * parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int
```

Comment: This is probably a bit over-engineered for python. You probably want to start the method be setting param2 to a default and then changing it to a string or an int as needed at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(this, foo_str, bar_int):
        this.__foo = foo_str
        this.__bar = bar_int

    def foo(this, new=None):
        if new != None:
            try:
                this.__foo = str(new)
            except ValueError:
                print("Illegal value. foo unchanged.")

        return this.__foo

    def bar(this, new=None):
        if new != None:
            try:
                this.__bar = int(new)
            except ValueError:
                print("Illegal value. bar unchanged.")

        return this.__bar

obj = MyClass("test", 42)
print(obj.foo(), obj.bar())

print(obj.foo("tset"), obj.bar(24))

print(obj.foo(42), obj.bar("test"))

Output:
    test 42
    tset 24
    Illegal value. bar unchanged.
    42 24
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I think one very simple example is missing from all the answers, and that is: what to do when the only difference between variations on the method is the number of arguments. The answer still is to use a method with variable number of arguments.

Say, you start with a method that requires use of two arguments

```
def method(int_a, str_b):
    print("Got arguments: '{0}' and '{1}'".format(int_a, str_b)
```

then you need to add a variant with just the second argument (say, because the integer is redundant), the solution is very simple:

```
def _method_2_param(int_a, str_b):
    print("Got arguments: '{0}' and '{1}'".format(int_a, str_b))

def _method_1_param(str_b):
    print("Got argument: '{0}'".format(str_b))

def method(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) + len(kwargs) == 2:
        return _method_2_param(args, kwargs)
    elif len(args) + len(kwargs) == 1:
        return _method_1_param(args, kwargs)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Method requires one or two arguments")
```

The nice thing about this solution is that no matter if the calling code used keyword arguments or positional arguments before, it will still continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@overload` solves the thing: VS Code -> f12 on `open()` -> it shows a bunch of duplicates of the `open()` function:

```
@overload
def open(...):
@overload
def open(...):
...
```

So, here's the result...

```
from typing import overload

class MyClass:
""""""

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    """Constructor"""
@overload
def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String,parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String):
    print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String
    print parameter_B_that_Must_Be_String
@overload
def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int):
    print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String * parameter_A_that_Must_Be_Int
def my_method(self,parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String):
    print parameter_A_that_Must_Be_String
```

I'm sorry for being nervous...

Comment: Hi, `@overload` is just for static type checkers. It doesn't bring overloading behavior like what you see in other languages.

Comment: The files end with `.pyi` are stub files. They only contain type hints. You don't see any implementation there.