# <Python, openCV> How I can use cv2.ellipse?

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV2 for python have 2 function

---

#### [Function 1]

- Python: cv2.ellipse(img, center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) → None

#### [Function 2]

- Python: cv2.ellipse(img, box, color[, thickness[, lineType]]) → None

---

I want to use [Function 1]

But when I use this Code

> cv2.ellipse(ResultImage, Circle, Size, Angle, 0, 360, Color, 2, cv2.CV_AA, 0)

It raise

> TypeError: ellipse() takes at most 5 arguments (10 given)

---

Could you help me?

Comment: Please mention your Python and OpenCV version! At least I can confirm that the ellipse function is working fine with Python 2.6.1 and OpenCV 2.4.3

Comment: I have the same error with python 2.7.5 and OpenCV 2.4.3. And I'm definitely passing tuples of length 2 for the "center" and "axes" arguments.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that Python [doesn't support multiple dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079643/777285) by default doesn't help here: having two functions with the same name but different parameters is not pythonic. So the question is: how does `cv2` guess the version we'd like to call ? I couldn't find any explicit doc on that.

Anyhow, after experiencing the same issue with opencv 3.0.0-beta and Python 3.4.2, I finally found out that in my case one of the circle's point was a `float`, and although I was running the official samples code with 8 parameters, for some reason cv2 defaulted to the 5-args function. Using `int` fixed the problem, so the error message was pretty misleading.

I believe going from Python 2 to 3 may bring that kind of confusion in existing code, since [integer divisions return floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float) in Python 3.

Comment: Nitpick: this is not called "multiple dispatch" but rather "function overloading".

Comment: Yes I've grown up with the 'method overloading' vocabulary too, in Java. It's only when writing this post that I learnt about the 'multiple dispatch' wording, which [does seem to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Python)

Comment: Multiple dispatch refers to something different than function overloading---multifunctions switch based on runtime types, as opposed to compiler-checked strictly typed functions, which would be function overloading. See for example this C++ report on multimethods: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2216.pdf

Comment: @alkasm, owing to the fact that python is dynamically typed, shall I assume that *multiple dispatch* is the correct term here then ?

Comment: I believe so. GvR also similarly calls them multimethods, not function overloads, in his example from your prev link, here: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605, so I think your wording is fine. On the other hand, while Python doesn't have the functionality built-in, I'm not sure it's quite unpythonic. For example numpy arrays have different dtypes but the same functions can be called with any type arrays. Those types don't exist at the Python level (they're all just ndarrays) but they *could* be and it would be equally intuitive an interface.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure all the ellipse parameters are **int** otherwise it raises "TypeError: ellipse() takes at most 5 arguments (10 given)". Had the same problem and casting the parameters to int, fixed it.

Please note that in Python, you should round the number first and then use int(), since int function will cut the number:

x = 2.7 , int(x)  will be 2 **not 3**

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error and it turned out that I was not passing the correct minimum number of parameters (7) to the startAngle/endAngle form of the method.  In my case I was missing the "angle" parameter (the angle of rotation of the ellipse), which precedes the startAngle and endAngle parameter.

My guess is that your "Circle" or "Size" parameters are wrong...they should be tuples,
(x,y) for center and (width,height) for axes

```
cv2.ellipse(ResultImage, (centerX,centerY), (width,height), 0, 0, 180, yellow, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers correctly point out that calling the `[Function 1]` version requires using `int` coordinates in some of the arguments (`center` and `axes`, specifically). However, they don't mention that you can use the `shift` argument to maintain "fractional bit" accuracy in the coordinates for sub-integer resolution.

Here's an example wrapper function for `cv2.ellipse` that can accept `float` coordinates and cast them to `int`s after rewriting them for use with the `shift` argument:

```py
def draw_ellipse(
        img, center, axes, angle,
        startAngle, endAngle, color,
        thickness=3, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, shift=10):
    center = (
        int(round(center[0] * 2**shift)),
        int(round(center[1] * 2**shift))
    )
    axes = (
        int(round(axes[0] * 2**shift)),
        int(round(axes[1] * 2**shift))
    )
    cv2.ellipse(
        img, center, axes, angle,
        startAngle, endAngle, color,
        thickness, lineType, shift)
```

The `shift` parameter indicates the number of "fractional bits" in the `center` and `axes` coordinate values, so that's why the coordinates multiplied by powers of 2 (multiplying by 2 is the same as shifting the bits in their integer binary representations to the left by one.) This `shift` trick is handy with many other opencv functions, as well, but its usage isn't documented very well (especially in python).

Answer (score 0):

these parameters should be integer, or it will raise TypeError