# Draw an arc by using end-points and bulge distance. In OpenCV or PIL

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, dxf

Working on a script to convert dxf to png, I need to draw arc which are having only three parameters, i.e. Start point of arc, end point of arc and bulge distance.

I have checked OpenCV and PIL both, and they require start and end angle to draw this arc. I can find out those angles using some geometry, but would like to know if there is any other solution out there which I am missing out.

Comment: Down voting a question without giving any reason is awful. Let me know the reason and I can update question if required.

Comment: What's wrong with using geometry? This isn't something which will take any significant amount of processing, it'll just be a few operations and done. Note that, at least for OpenCV, the idea is that you draw an ellipse but only from one starting angle to and ending angle (this is after all what an arc is). How about you post the code attempting the above solution (with whatever libraries you like) and post what issue you have with it?

Comment: Take a vector (with length the given bugle distance) extending perpendicularly from the middle of the line formed by your endpoints to get a third point on your circle. From these three points, as is well known, you can calculate the center and radius of the circle passing through the points (which would be the arc) [using determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460096/246399). Then with the center you can simply calculate the angle to the original endpoints, giving you angles, center, radius, and so on, to draw your arcs with OpenCV or PIL.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderReynolds for pointing out this solution. I was solving it using elliptic curve, but the idea of having three points lying on a circle (of some different radius and center) is much better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have three pieces of information defining your circular arc: two points on the circle (defining a *chord* of that circle) and the bulge distance (called the *sagitta* of the circular arc).

See the following graphic:

[image: Circular arc notation]

Here *s* is the sagitta, *l* is half the chord-length, and *r* is of course the radius. Other important non-marked positions are the points which the chord intersects the circle, the point where the sagitta intersects the circle, and the center of the circle, from which the radius is extending.

For OpenCV's [`ellipse()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse) function, we would use the following prototype:

```
cv2.ellipse(img, center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) → img
```

where most of the parameters are described by the following graphic:

[image: cv2.ellipse params]

Since we're drawing a circular, not elliptical arc, the major/minor axes will have the same size and there's no difference rotating it, so the axes will just be `(radius, radius)` and the `angle` should be zero to simplify. Then the only parameters we need are the center of the circle, the radius, and the start angle and ending angle of drawing, corresponding to the points of the chord. The angles are easy to calculate (they're just some angles on the circle). So ultimately we need to find the radius and center of the circle.

Finding the radius and the center is the same as finding the equation of the circle, so there are a ton of ways to do it. But since we're programming here, the easiest way IMO is to define a third point on the circle by where the sagitta touches the circle, and then solve for the circle from those three points.

So first we'll need to get the midpoint of the chord, get a perpendicular line to that midpoint, and extend it the length of the sagitta to get to that third point, but that's easy enough. I'll start given `pt1 = (x1, y1)` and `pt2 = (x2, y2)` as my two points on the circle and `sagitta` is the 'bulge depth' (i.e. the parameters you have):

```
# extract point coordinates
x1, y1 = pt1
x2, y2 = pt2

# find normal from midpoint, follow by length sagitta
n = np.array([y2 - y1, x1 - x2])
n_dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(n**2))

if np.isclose(n_dist, 0):
    # catch error here, d(pt1, pt2) ~ 0
    print('Error: The distance between pt1 and pt2 is too small.')

n = n/n_dist
x3, y3 = (np.array(pt1) + np.array(pt2))/2 + sagitta * n
```

Now we've got the third point on the circle. Note that the sagitta is just some length, so it could go either direction---if sagitta were negative, it'd go one direction from the chord, and if it were positive, it'd go the other direction. Not sure if this is how that distance is given to you or not.

Then we can simply [use determinants to solve for the radius and center](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460096/246399).

```
# calculate the circle from three points
# see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460096/246399
A = np.array([
    [x1**2 + y1**2, x1, y1, 1],
    [x2**2 + y2**2, x2, y2, 1],
    [x3**2 + y3**2, x3, y3, 1]])
M11 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (1, 2, 3)])
M12 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 2, 3)])
M13 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 1, 3)])
M14 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 1, 2)])

if np.isclose(M11, 0):
    # catch error here, the points are collinear (sagitta ~ 0)
    print('Error: The third point is collinear.')

cx = 0.5 * M12/M11
cy = -0.5 * M13/M11
radius = np.sqrt(cx**2 + cy**2 + M14/M11)
```

Then lastly, as we need the starting and ending angles to draw the ellipse with OpenCV, we can just use `atan2()` to get the angles from the center to the initial points:

```
# calculate angles of pt1 and pt2 from center of circle
pt1_angle = 180*np.arctan2(y1 - cy, x1 - cx)/np.pi
pt2_angle = 180*np.arctan2(y2 - cy, x2 - cx)/np.pi
```

So I packaged this all up into one function:

```
def convert_arc(pt1, pt2, sagitta):

    # extract point coordinates
    x1, y1 = pt1
    x2, y2 = pt2

    # find normal from midpoint, follow by length sagitta
    n = np.array([y2 - y1, x1 - x2])
    n_dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(n**2))

    if np.isclose(n_dist, 0):
        # catch error here, d(pt1, pt2) ~ 0
        print('Error: The distance between pt1 and pt2 is too small.')

    n = n/n_dist
    x3, y3 = (np.array(pt1) + np.array(pt2))/2 + sagitta * n

    # calculate the circle from three points
    # see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460096/246399
    A = np.array([
        [x1**2 + y1**2, x1, y1, 1],
        [x2**2 + y2**2, x2, y2, 1],
        [x3**2 + y3**2, x3, y3, 1]])
    M11 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (1, 2, 3)])
    M12 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 2, 3)])
    M13 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 1, 3)])
    M14 = np.linalg.det(A[:, (0, 1, 2)])

    if np.isclose(M11, 0):
        # catch error here, the points are collinear (sagitta ~ 0)
        print('Error: The third point is collinear.')

    cx = 0.5 * M12/M11
    cy = -0.5 * M13/M11
    radius = np.sqrt(cx**2 + cy**2 + M14/M11)

    # calculate angles of pt1 and pt2 from center of circle
    pt1_angle = 180*np.arctan2(y1 - cy, x1 - cx)/np.pi
    pt2_angle = 180*np.arctan2(y2 - cy, x2 - cx)/np.pi

    return (cx, cy), radius, pt1_angle, pt2_angle
```

With these values you can then the arc with OpenCV's `ellipse()` function. However, these are all floating point values. `ellipse()` does let you plot floating point values with the `shift` argument, but if you're not familiar with it it's a little weird, so instead we can borrow the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892317/5087436) to define a function

```
def draw_ellipse(
        img, center, axes, angle,
        startAngle, endAngle, color,
        thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, shift=10):
    # uses the shift to accurately get sub-pixel resolution for arc
    # taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892317/5087436
    center = (
        int(round(center[0] * 2**shift)),
        int(round(center[1] * 2**shift))
    )
    axes = (
        int(round(axes[0] * 2**shift)),
        int(round(axes[1] * 2**shift))
    )
    return cv2.ellipse(
        img, center, axes, angle,
        startAngle, endAngle, color,
        thickness, lineType, shift)
```

Then to use these functions it's as simple as:

```
img = np.zeros((500, 500), dtype=np.uint8)
pt1 = (50, 50)
pt2 = (350, 250)
sagitta = 50

center, radius, start_angle, end_angle = convert_arc(pt1, pt2, sagitta)
axes = (radius, radius)
draw_ellipse(img, center, axes, 0, start_angle, end_angle, 255)
cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Drawn arc]

And again note that a negative sagitta gives an arc the other direction:

```
center, radius, start_angle, end_angle = convert_arc(pt1, pt2, sagitta)
axes = (radius, radius)
draw_ellipse(img, center, axes, 0, start_angle, end_angle, 255)
center, radius, start_angle, end_angle = convert_arc(pt1, pt2, -sagitta)
axes = (radius, radius)
draw_ellipse(img, center, axes, 0, start_angle, end_angle, 127)
cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Negative sagitta]

---

Lastly just to expand, I broke out two error cases in the `convert_arc()` function. First:

```
if np.isclose(n_dist, 0):
    # catch error here, d(pt1, pt2) ~ 0
    print('Error: The distance between pt1 and pt2 is too small.')
```

The error catch here is because we need to get a unit vector, so we need to divide by the length which can't be zero. Of course, this will only happen if `pt1` and `pt2` are the same point, so you can just check that they're unique at the top of the function instead of checking here.

Second:

```
if np.isclose(M11, 0):
    # catch error here, the points are collinear (sagitta ~ 0)
    print('Error: The third point is collinear.')
```

Here only happens if the three points are collinear, which only happens if the sagitta is 0. So again, you can check this at the top of your function (and maybe say, OK, if it is 0, then just draw a line from `pt1` to `pt2` or whatever you want to do).

Comment: Thanks for the precise solution.