# how to draw a circular arc using 2 extreme points, radius and center in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I have the extreme/corner points of an arc, along with its radius and center coordinates. How to draw an arc using opencv using what I have?
I need to draw an arc with a different color between these two points
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Corner points + center + radius overdetermine an arc, you may specify 2 points and either the radius or the center for solution to exist. Please provide a diagram (handdrawn is totally OK!) to clarify the question.

Anyway, look into `cv2.ellipse` and try to express your problem in its arguments' terms.

Comment: cv2.ellipse takes angle, but I have extreme points, how do I map these together?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145096/draw-an-arc-by-using-end-points-and-bulge-distance-in-opencv-or-pil

Comment: calculate vectors from circle center to each point, then calculate angle for each vector