# How to make an arc using cv2.ecllipse between two coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have the x and y coordinate of two points in an image I want to make an arc that starts from one point and ends at another, I am using OpenCV,ie, cv2.ecllipse function but the problem is instead of start and end angles i have coordinates of two points can someone help how to do that or use some other function/ library to make arc between 2 points

My code right now:

```
#ecllipse 
            start_angle = 180 * np.arctan2(coordinates[3][0] - coordinates[2][0], coordinates[3][1] - coordinates[2][1])/ np.pi
            end_angle = 180 * np.arctan2(coordinates[2][0] - coordinates[1][0], coordinates[2][1] - coordinates[1][1])/ np.pi

            # Calculate center of the ellipse
            center = (coordinates[2][0], coordinates[2][1])

            # Draw the ellipse
            cv2.ellipse(frame, (int(center[0] * frame.shape[1]), int(center[1] * frame.shape[0])), 
                        (100, 100), start_angle, end_angle, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)  # -1 for filled ellipse
```

to make an arc using two points rather two angles

To add more clarity [elbow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEAXg.png)

I want an arc to represent the elbow angle, I have the coordinates of the line so i just want a way to make an arc

[Required arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G29Yr.jpg)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145096/draw-an-arc-by-using-end-points-and-bulge-distance-in-opencv-or-pil

Comment: Two points aren't sufficient to determine the arc. I could draw an infinity of circular arcs that passed through two points. For an ellipse there are even more possibilities, as you would have one more degree of freedom. So, clarify your constraints a bit more.

Comment: @lastchance i have added more info and an image for refernce

Comment: Doesn't that make three points, not two? Can you put your required ellipse in the diagram?

Comment: @lastchance I have added the required arc image I have the radius the centre of arc just can it to be between those two lines

Comment: If the centre of the arc is point 2 (as your code shows) then the start angle should be based on (point 1 - point 2) and the end angle should be based on (point 3 - point 2) ... or possibly vice versa if the points are in the opposite order. Apart from the order of points in the subtraction that seems to be very nearly what your code shows.