# extending an overloaded class __init__ and making the child classes __init__ compatible with the overloaded class?

Tags: python, class, overloading, init

Say class A has an **init** that is overloaded? How do I overload the **init** in the first place where it takes more than 1 argument set?

Also, when extending to a child class how can I make sure the child **init** is compatible with the overloaded parent init?

Comment: Please consider making this question clearer with some example code demonstrating what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support function overload since it's a dynamic language, see:
[Overloaded functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113032/overloaded-functions-in-python)

If I understand you correctly, you need `super` to call the method of your base class from your child class:

```
In [95]: class Base(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, x):
    ...:         print 'in Base.ctor, x is:', x
    ...: 
    ...: class Child(Base):
    ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
    ...:         super(Child, self).__init__(x)

In [96]: c = Child(1,2)
in Base.ctor, x is: 1
```

see: [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: `super(self.__class__, self)` is broken if inheritance continues -- try a `class Grandchild(Child): pass` and see what happens on instantiating if.  In Python 2, you need to be explicit in `super`, using `super(Child, self)` in this case.