# How to add method overriding & overloading to Bank Account in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, tkinter, overloading

I am very new to python let alone Tkinter, and am creating an object oriented bank account, i have a working program, however when designing the application i planned to add all the features of OOP into the code, how would i add method overriding and overloading to this program whilst keeping its full functionality? Give your insight.

### Bank Account Code

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time

class Account:
    def __init__(self, init_balance=0):
        self.balance = init_balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
    def get_balance(self, init_balance, rate):
        return self.get_balance() * self._rate

class InterestAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, init_balance=0, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__(init_balance)
        self._rate = rate
    def interest(self):
        return self.balance * self._rate

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
       Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Bank Account')

        #Menu#
        menu = Menu(self)
        acct_type_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Account Type', menu=acct_type_menu)
        acct_type_menu.add_command(label='Standard', command=self.set_type_standard)
        acct_type_menu.add_command(label='Interest', command=self.set_type_interest)
        self.config(menu=menu)

        #Account#
        start_balance = randint(100, 500)
        self.acct = Account(start_balance)
        self.my_interest = InterestAccount(start_balance)
        self.interest = self.my_interest.balance + self.my_interest.interest()

        #Labels#
        Label(self, text='Current Balance:').pack()
        self.balance_label = Label(self, text='Error: Select account type')
        self.balance_label.pack()

        #Button#
        btns_frame = Frame(self)
        btns_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        Button(btns_frame, text='Deposit', width=13, command=self.deposit).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(btns_frame, text='Withdraw', width=13, command=self.withdraw).pack(side=RIGHT)

        #Textbox#

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%S')
        self.text = Entry(self, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
        self.text.pack()

    def onValidate(self, S):
        if S in '0123456789.':
            return True
        return False

    def set_type_standard(self):
        self.acct_type = 'standard'
        self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.acct.balance, 2))

    def set_type_interest(self):
        self.acct_type = 'interest'
        self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.interest, 2))

    def clear_entry(self):
        self.text.delete(0, END)

    def deposit(self): 
        if self.acct_type == 'interest':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.interest += a
            self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.interest, 2))
        elif self.acct_type == 'standard':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.acct.balance += a
            self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.acct.balance, 2))
        else:
            self.balance_label.config(text='Error: Select account type')
            self.clear_entry()

    def withdraw(self):
        if self.acct_type == 'interest':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.interest -= a
            self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.interest, 2))
        elif self.acct_type == 'standard':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.acct.balance -= a
            self.balance_label.config(text=round(self.acct.balance, 2))
        else:
            self.balance_label.config(text='Error: Select account type')
        self.clear_entry()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, and too broad. Why is simply creating a method in a subclass different than what you are asking for? What exactly are you wanting to override and overload?

Comment: Is method overloading and overriding already implemented with my code? If so can you highlight where please, as i said im new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Function overloading (also method overloading) is a programming concept that allows programmers to define two or more functions with the same name and in the same scope.

You already have some "overloading" in your code:

```
class InterestAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, init_balance=0, rate=0.1):
```

When creating a new `InterestAccount` object, it can be called with 0, 1, or 2 parameters because of those default values specified. As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113061/5673922), Python is dynamically-typed, so you don't need to create multiple of the same method with different parameters like you do in Java.

> Overriding is an object-oriented programming feature that enables a child class to provide different implementation for a method that is already defined and/or implemented in its parent class...

You have a great opportunity to override the `deposit` and `withdraw` methods in your `InterestAccount` class because it inherits from `Account` and currently uses its parent's implementations of these methods. Simply define `deposit` and `withdraw` methods in your `InterestAccount` class, but do something different than what is done in the parent class.

Comment: Can you show me a coded example , im more of a visual learner,  of how i could override , it would help alot.

Comment: @MohamedIsmail It's already done in your code. Copy and paste the `deposit` and `withdraw` methods from `Account` into `InterestAccount`, then change both methods to accommodate for the interest. There is also a mistake in your `Account.get_balance` method. It should be `def get_balance(self): return self.balance`

Comment: Thank you very much nelson, you have been very helpful