# How can I type-hint a function where the return type depends on the input type of an argument?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Assume that I have a function which converts Python data-types to Postgres data-types like this:

```
def map_type(input):
    if isinstance(input, int):
        return MyEnum(input)
    elif isinstance(input, str):
        return MyCustomClass(str)
```

I could type-hint this as:

```
def map_type(input: Union[int, str]) -> Union[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]: ...
```

But then code like the following would fail to type-check even though it is correct:

```
myvar = map_type('foobar')
print(myvar.property_of_my_custom_class)
```

Complete example (working code, but errors in type-hinting):

```
from typing import Union
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    VALUE_1 = 1
    VALUE_2 = 2


class MyCustomClass:

    def __init__(self, value: str) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @property
    def myproperty(self) -> str:
        return 2 * self.value


def map_type(value: Union[int, str]) -> Union[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]:

    if isinstance(value, int):
        return MyEnum(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return MyCustomClass(value)
    raise TypeError('Invalid input type')


myvar1 = map_type(1)
print(myvar1.value, myvar1.name)

myvar2 = map_type('foobar')
print(myvar2.myproperty)
```

I'm aware that I could split up the mapping into two functions, but the aim is to have a generic type-mapping function.

I was also thinking about working with classes and polymorphism, but then how would I type-hint the topmost class methods? Because their output type would depend on the concrete instance type.

Comment: An issue is: presumably you don't know at runtime what the input value is, so you don't know what the output is either. So you must expect either type as a return value from the function.

Comment: Yes. But as I mentioned in the deleted answer, I think this may be a job for `singledispatch`. But I will leave the question open for now. Because if it really isn't doable, a "You can't" will be a good answer for this.

Comment: why don't you make it polymorphic by the signature? (don't know how this works in python but in scala you do that all the time), or define anonymus functions inside and return their type depending on what you get. Very interesting question BTW

Comment: @E.Serra do you have a link to a Scala example? Maybe I can take that as inspiration or at the very least as a source where I learn new terminology with which I can refine my Google searches ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is exactly what [function overloads](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading) are for.

In short, you do the following:

```
from typing import overload

# ...snip...

@overload
def map_type(value: int) -> MyEnum: ...

@overload
def map_type(value: str) -> MyCustomClass: ...

def map_type(value: Union[int, str]) -> Union[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return MyEnum(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return MyCustomClass(value)
    raise TypeError('Invalid input type')
```

Now, when you do `map_type(3)`, mypy will understand that the return type is `MyEnum`.

And at runtime, the only function to actually run is the final one -- the first two are completely overridden and ignored.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant, you do this in scala all the time, you don't even have to specify the overload because functions are bound to their signature.

Comment: This is old, but I wanted to add that you can also do this with actual values for your inputs by using the Literal object from typing. For example, if you want to change the output given the value of a boolean field, you can create an overload for Literal[True] and Literal[False]

Comment: It'd be great if there were something called, say, `UnionMatch`, which let's us do `def map_type(value: UnionMatch[int, str]) -> UnionMatch[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]:` so that the overloads don't need to be written. The vast majority of the overloads I'm writing are stupid simple, but repeating the signature is tedious when I have many of these types of functions

Answer (score 12):

**For output types that are identical or a variation of the input type**

You can use the follow strategy (and remove the need to add additional `@overload`s when more types are introduced/supported).

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")  # the variable name must coincide with the string

def filter_category(category: T) -> list[T]:
  # assume get_options() is some function that gets
  # an arbitrary number of objects of varying types
  return [
    option
    for option in get_options()
    if is subclass(option, category)
  ]
```

`filter_category` would correctly be associated by both your IDE (VSCode, Pycharm, etc) and by your static type checker (Mypy)

```
# for instance list_of_ints would show in your IDE as of type list[Type[int]]
list_of_ints = filter_category(int)

# or here it list_of_bools would show in your IDE as of type list[Type[bool]]
list_of_bools = filter_category(bool)
```

***Note: this doesn't answer every aspect of the question, only a subset, albeit a very common one***

Comment: While the code is correcct, it does not answer the question though. In the question, the return-type of the function is *different* from the argument-type. But it still *depends* on the argument-type. This is a small but very important distinction.

Comment: @exhuma you're totally correct, this is a subset of the question because it only answers for the cases where your output type *is* your input type or a variation of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write "dummy" functions without code in the body (except for a `pass`) with the right type hints for the return variables that fit to the changing input variables, which also should have type hints.

Mind that type hints do not have an influence on the code itself, you do not overload any function here. Best practice in Python is not to overload, see:

- [Overloaded functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113061/11154841)
- [NotImplementedError: You should not call an overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282679/11154841).

Overloading with the module `typing` does not really overload. The module `typing` is only for type hints. Type hints are just to give the reader a quick insight into what is going on, but the code runs through even if the type hints are wrong.

As far as I can oversee this as a beginner at type hints (feedback needed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113162/11154841)), your code should be as follows *(taking the easer Union="|" format from >=`Python 3.10` which also does not need an import anymore)*:

##### Your code

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import overload


class MyEnum(Enum):
    VALUE_1 = 1
    VALUE_2 = 2


class MyCustomClass:

    def __init__(self, value: str) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @property
    def myproperty(self) -> str:
        return 2 * self.value

@overload
def map_type(value: int) -> MyEnum:
    pass

@overload
def map_type(value: str) -> MyCustomClass:
    pass

def map_type(value: int|str) -> MyEnum|MyCustomClass:

    if isinstance(value, int):
        return MyEnum(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return MyCustomClass(value)
    raise TypeError('Invalid input type')


myvar1 = map_type(1)
print(myvar1.value, myvar1.name)

myvar2 = map_type('foobar')
print(myvar2.myproperty)
```

Checking the type hints with [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) from the Powershell prompt:

```bash
[some_path]> mypy .\my_test.py
```

Returns `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

##### My own test code

But in my own tests with another setting, I had to drop the type hints of the return variables in the "non-overloaded" function. The setting was:

- 2+1 return variables

  - 1st return variable was a mere string, not worth listing here.
  - 2nd return variable:

    - The second return variable could be either tk.Entry or tk.Label; it was a tk.Label if the function was called with a third optional string argument.
    - Both tk.Entry and tk.Label had to be built at every initiation of the class to show up and work in the GUI, thus, the function had to be called twice, once with and once without the optional argument.
  - A third optional tk.StringVar return variable was needed only if the tk.Label was built, so that its text could be changed afterwards with `set(text)`.

The error:

```bash
.py:120: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[Label, Entry]", expected "Tuple[Label, Union[Entry, Label], Optional[StringVar]]")  [return-value]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

If you run into this error, make different return variables for the two different tkinter objects, I named them tkentry_right and tklabel_right. Again from my own test code:

```py
...
        @overload
        def make_left_Label_and_right_widget(
            master: tk.Tk, row: int, left_text: str
        ) -> Tuple[tk.Label, tk.Entry]:
            """
            Args:
                master: the root of the GUI App
                row: the row in the grid (0 means at the top, 1 is one below, aso.)
                left_text: what is written on the left Label next to the right Entry widget
            Returns:
                None
            """
            pass

        @overload
        def make_left_Label_and_right_widget(
            master: tk.Tk, row: int, left_text: str, right_text: str
        ) -> Tuple[tk.Label, tk.Label, tk.StringVar]:
            """
            Args:
                master: the root of the GUI App
                row: the row in the grid (0 means at the top, 1 is one below, aso.)
                left_text: what is written on the left Label next to the right Label widget
                right_text: what is written on the right Label widget
            Returns:
                None
            """
            pass

        def make_left_Label_and_right_widget(
            master: tk.Tk, row: int, left_text: str, right_text: str | None = None
        ):
            """Creates the application variable with its text value.
            Fills the label widget with this new tk.StringVar.
            Puts it in the grid of the GUI.

            Args:
                master: the root of the GUI App
                row: the row in the grid (0 means at the top, 1 is one below, aso.)
                left_text: what is written on the left Label next to the right widget
                right_text: what is written on the right Label widget, if there is any
            Returns:
                tklab_txt_left: the left Label widget next to the right widget
            Returns (1):
                tkentry_right: the right widget, here Entry
            Returns (2):
                tklabel_right: the right widget, here Label
                tkstringvar_right_label: the tk StringVar as the value of the Label
                    It can even be changed after running mainloop().
            """
...
            if right_text is None:
...
                return tklab_txt_left, tkentry_right
            else:
...
                return tklab_txt_left, tklabel_right, tkstringvar_right_label
```

And then just drop the type hints of the return variables since they are clear from the @overload functions.

##### Back to your code

In the following, the unneeded type hints are commented out (and can also be dropped). *Do this only if `mypy` does not run through*:

```py
def map_type(value: Union[int, str]): # -> Union[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]:
```