# How to type-hint a function return based on input parameter value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

How can I type-hint a function in Python based on the *value* of an input parameter?

For instance, consider the following snippet:

```
from typing import Iterable

def build(
    source: Iterable,
    factory: type
) -> ?: # what can I write here?
    return factory(source)

as_list = build('hello', list) # -> list ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
as_set = build('hello', set) # -> set {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'}
```

When building `as_list`, the value of `factory` is `list`, and this should be the type annotation.

I am aware of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445559/how-can-i-type-hint-a-function-where-the-return-type-depends-on-the-input-type-o), but, in that case, the return type depended only on the input *types*, not on their *values*.
I would like to have `def build(source: Iterable, factory: type) -> factory`, but of course this doesn't work.

I am also aware of [Literal types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) in Python 3.8+, and something similar to this could be achieved:

```
from typing import Iterable, Literal, overload
from enum import Enum

FactoryEnum = Enum('FactoryEnum', 'LIST SET')

@overload
def build(source: Iterable, factory: Literal[FactoryEnum.LIST]) -> list: ...

@overload
def build(source: Iterable, factory: Literal[FactoryEnum.SET]) -> set: ...
```

But this solution would make `factory` useless (I could just define two functions `build_list(source) -> list` and `build_set(source) -> set`).

How can this be done?

Comment: Rather than `type`, why isn't `factory` e.g. `Callable[[Iterable], T]`? Then the return value is `T` (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics).

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is actually a great idea, I don't know how I missed that. Would you mind writing an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `type`, you could use a [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) and define the `factory` as a `Callable`, as follows:

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def build(
    source: Iterable,
    factory: Callable[[Iterable], T]
) -> T:
    return factory(source)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This answer emphasizes the fact that classes are themselves callables.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing, but return the type of the Iterable if no factory is called ?
```
def build(
    source: Iterable[S],
    factory: Optional[Callable[[Iterable], T]] = None
) -> T if factory is not None else S:
```

Comment: @th0mash I think you'd have to do that as [overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).