# Type hint function where return type depends on input list item type

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-type, type-hinting

What is the best type hint for a function that returns an item from an input argument which is a list?

Here is the function:

```py
def ask_mcq(title: str, prompt: str, options: list) -> ???:
    ...snip...
    v = tk.IntVar()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        tk.Radiobutton(root, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    ...snip...
    return options[v.get()]
```

I tried checking other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445559/how-can-i-type-hint-a-function-where-the-return-type-depends-on-the-input-type-o), but none of them seem to answer this question in specific. I am not an expert.

---

**EDIT:** By reading the comments and answers, I realize now that the question doesn't really make sense in the case where I ask the user to choose an option. It's better to return a string and handle it afterwards. I accepted @balderman's answer because it's the most applicable to this unlikely situation.

Comment: What kind of types the list can hold?

Comment: @balderman im trying to make it generic, so it can hold anything a list can hold. 
edit: is this bad programming?

Comment: OK - see my answer below

Comment: @balderman thank you for your answer. So im guessing if I don't know the item type the list will hold then I cant really type hint it? 
Does this mean somehow that the function is badly coded? edit: typo

Comment: It depends on the problem you try to solve. Most of the time a list does not hold "anything" so if you know the actual types at the time you write the code - it can be much better to use them (and not `Any`)

Comment: I'm actually a little confused how options can be a list of `Any`, I'm pretty sure that the `text` arg in `tk.Radiobutton` has to be strictly of type `str`? Won't your code not work properly if options has non-strings?

Comment: The code will work since type annotations are ignored in run time. If you know that options is a list of `str` --> change the Any to str

Comment: @MilanLeonard You're maybe right, the situation seems unlikely but can't I convert to str and at the end return the actual type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example below (assuming `options` is a list of `Any`)

```
from typing import List,Any


def ask_mcq(title: str, prompt: str, options: List[Any]) -> Any:
    return options[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question's answer you are linking specifies the solution rather clearly. You should use function overloads to return a value from the list, and inside the function check what possible values it can take (with the if statement in the question's answer), and returning a typed variable.

I think your code would look something like this:

```
from typing import overload

# ...snip...

@overload
def map_type(value: int) -> MyEnum: ...

@overload
def map_type(value: str) -> MyCustomClass: ...


def ask_mcq(title: str, prompt: str, options: list) -> Union[MyEnum, MyCustomClass]:
    ...snip...
    v = tk.IntVar()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        tk.Radiobutton(root, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    ...snip...

    if isinstance(options[v.get()], int):
        return MyEnum(options[v.get()])
    elif isinstance(options[v.get()], str):
        return MyCustomClass(options[v.get()])
    raise TypeError('Invalid input type')
```

EDIT: If the list can take any value, @balderman's answer is more adequate.