# NotImplementedError: You should not call an overloaded function

Tags: python, overloading

```
@overload
def setSize(self,size:tuple[int|str])->None:
    '''
    Set image size (width,height)
    '''
    try:self.options.append(f"width=\"{str(size[0])}\" height=\"{str(size[1])}\"")
    except IndexError:print("Error reading the size, aborting")
@overload
def setSize(self,width:int|str,height:int|str)->None:
    '''
    Set image Size
    '''
    self.setSize((width,height))
```

This is my code and I called this function as
var.setSize((500,500)) which would normally call the top one but I got this error:

```
NotImplementedError: You should not call an overloaded function. A series of @overload-decorated functions outside a stub module should always be followed by an implementation that is not @overload-ed.
```

Comment: From the error message, it looks like one of the functions has to be declared without the `@overload` annotation. Have you tried that?

Comment: But then how do I know which one will run aren't they both blueprints for the instance of one of the parameters being met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing code with function overloading in Python, it is important to remember that

> [y]ou should not call an overloaded function. A series of @overload-decorated functions outside a stub module should always be followed by an implementation that is not @overload-ed.

This is because @overload-ed functions are intended to simply declare the types of the arguments without providing an actual implementation. Therefore, an implementation must be provided following the @overload-ed functions in order for the code to be valid.