# Is it possible to let a function's generic return type be based on the last of variadic positional arguments?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I want to implement a function which can be called with one or more callables as arguments and let the return type be the same as the the return type of the last provided callable.

So (without the type hinting) I want to be able to call e.g. `foo()` the following ways:

```py
foo(lambda: "hello")             # -> str
foo(lambda: "hello", str.upper)  # -> str
foo(lambda: "hello", len)        # -> int
```

which could be implemented like this:

```py
def foo(first_fn, *more_fns):
    result = first_fn()
    for fn in more_fns:
        result = fn(result)
    return result
```

...if you were not interested in type hinting.

But trying to make `foo()` type aware in a basic way I'd like to write something like:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, Any

T = TypeVar("T")

def foo(*fns: Callable[..., Any], fnN: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
   ...
```

which unfortunately can't be called the same way anymore because `*fns` makes `fnN` (coming after `*`) a keyword-only argument.

I could go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113162/1668622) approach and provide a bunch of explicit signatures like this one:

```py
def foo(
    fn1: Callable[..., Any],
    fn2: Callable[..., Any],
    fnN: Callable[..., T],
) -> T:
    return fnN(fn2(fn1()))
    
print(f"{foo(lambda: 1, lambda x: 2*x, lambda y: str(y))!r}")
```

...but that doesn't feel good (as it would limit the number of possible arguments).

Another approach would be to reverse the call logic and have a `foo(fn_N, ..., fn_1)` semantic, but this would be sacrificing an intuitive signature for type hinting.

Maybe I'm only missing a syntactic way to write a function with *variadic positional only* arguments with the last argument named explicitly (to provide explicit type hinting) while keeping it positional.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not so good with typing in Python, but would `def foo(*fns: tuple[*Callable[..., Any], Callable[..., T]]) -> T:` help?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Star parameters in Python are typed with a single element’s type, not the type of the whole tuple.

Comment: `def foo(fns: tuple[Callable[..., Any], ..., Callable[..., T]]) -> T:` would be _syntactially_ correct, but I didn't manage `T` to become the desired type. Also `foo` would have to be called with a tuple and `mypy` complains about the inner `...`

Comment: These types of problems are typically better converted into a builder pattern. Is the number of arguments `foo` is called with ever determined at runtime?

Comment: No, I don't need the number of arguments, but I want `foo()` to have the correct return-type (in terms of type hinting). So I want the last snippet in my question to be generic rather than accepting exactly three arguments. The second snippet (first definition of `foo`) does this but without the typing.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without writing a mypy plugin, and someone has already done that. If you are open to adding a dependency, returns (https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pipeline.html) is a library that implements this kind of pipelining with static type checking. It also comes with a handful of other functional programming tools.

Comment: Or, consider making `foo` take a variable number of functions, and return a function that takes a single argument, whose return type is the desired final return type. So you would then call it as `foo(fn1, fn2, ...)(fnN)` without changing the order. This only works if you don't care about the return types of fn1, fn2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable using [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple). Here's a draft implementation:

> For mypy, this requires the following incomplete features:
>
> ```ini
> # mypy.ini
> [mypy]
> enable_incomplete_feature = TypeVarTuple, Unpack
> ```
>
> PEP 646 isn't fully supported at the moment in mypy, and will crash with more than one extra callable, but the following implementation should be valid (tested in pyright; see [pyright playground](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIAEkfAmUC_41SXUvDQBB8v1-x5CmRmr4HFKX4hSBSqiClHNtkzwave-HuWu2_d_NhsUrRQMhldmdu5vaMd2vQ2mzixpPWUK8b5yMgs4sYa8dBqQGLu6bmV00fkTi0FcAAUUndQMxnL49XenJ7Nbm_e7gpFMgz8EpnLZWdVo7LsmWVH6rrmMJZS9019Iw-TaZJ1sHXHGbfK7NNYylNWlg6lLqIuduStw4rVZEB41xqah-iNlyIeD5Ba3FpaT5fjGAq7ziD03OY9r6SJLlFriyJ_RVBiYHgfUWegB04gbxgvYBkFLjBEKiCmoV5ZPtO-LiHmF_ybjHqusb952Tt5MQNh0KqT9xg-TaPbdD5_rcNLOQDsUFJUi1E73-xMIIlDBEcE8j8PO4DQh1-xvv7RL88jEeHKQTtDHWr3pSnsLFRhvmllvYjNs6DYdkT9gIdfsjhtF9ng5ZcUh7KYtTTltBquZeUtoYtrpcVFpCsyFqXjKAHQBcQok919hvJMvUJf2vrBAIDAAA%3D)).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    R = t.TypeVar("R")
    FnsT = t.TypeVarTuple("FnsT")

@t.overload
def foo(first_fn: cx.Callable[[], R], /) -> R:
    """Handles the case where no other callables are passed in"""

@t.overload
def foo(
    first_fn: cx.Callable[[], t.Any],
    /,
    *more_fns: t.Unpack[tuple[t.Unpack[FnsT], cx.Callable[[t.Any], R]]],
) -> R:
    """Handles the case where at least one extra callable is passed in"""

def foo(first_fn: cx.Callable[[], t.Any], /, *more_fns: t.Any) -> t.Any:
    result = first_fn()
    for fn in more_fns:
        result = fn(result)
    return result
```

```
>>> reveal_type(foo(lambda: "hello"))  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
>>> reveal_type(foo(lambda: "hello", str.upper))  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
>>> reveal_type(foo(lambda: "hello", len))  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

It's not as strictly typed as one might wish for; the variadic `*more_fns` isn't able to pick up that a preceding callable's return type may not be compatible with a succeeding callable's argument type, but maybe for your purposes this is sufficient.

Comment: **_**magic**_**

Comment: @frans Oops - I just tried this with more than one extra callable, and mypy's crashing. PEP 646 isn't fully supported in mypy, but it's actively being worked on right at the moment, so this should work properly in the next version (mypy 1.6?).