# Overload decorator in typings module doesn't seem to behave as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, strong-typing

```
>>> from typing import overload

>>> @overload
... def hello(s: int):
...     return "Got an integer!"

>>> def hello(s: str):
...     return "Got a string"
```

Why does the calling `hello(1)` call the function with the string argument? Ideally, the `@overload` operator should handle it, right?

Comment: You need to decorate both definitions, otherwise you're just overriding whatever `hello` was with a normal function.

Comment: To be precise, only stub functions should be decorated. Calling decorated function will raise `NotImplementedError`. The idea of `overload` **is to overwrite stubs** with actual implementation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, python does not allow function overloading. Each time you think you are overloading function, you are just overwriting previous function declaration. Quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload):

> The @overload decorator allows describing functions and methods that
>   support multiple different combinations of argument types. A series of
>   @overload-decorated definitions must be followed by exactly one
>   non-@overload-decorated definition (for the same function/method). **The
>   @overload-decorated definitions are for the benefit of the type
>   checker only, since they will be overwritten by the
>   non-@overload-decorated definition, while the latter is used at
>   runtime but should be ignored by a type checker**. At runtime, calling a
>   @overload-decorated function directly will raise NotImplementedError.

The correct usage of `typing.overload` is as follows:

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def hello(s: int) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def hello(s: str) -> str:
    ...


def hello(s):
    if isinstance(s, int):
        return "Got an integer!"
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return "Got a string"
    raise ValueError('You must pass either int or str')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hello(1))
```

To show the actual benefit of `typing.overload` lets change `def hello(s: int)` to return `int` instead of `str`:

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def hello(s: int) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def hello(s: str) -> str:
    ...


def hello(s):
    if isinstance(s, int):
        return "Got an integer!"
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return "Got a string"
    raise ValueError('You must pass either int or str')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hello(1))
    a = hello(1) + 1
    b = hello(1) + 'a'
```

Note, that the actual implementation still returns `str` - python does not perform any checks here. However, PyCharm raises a warning:

[image]

`mypy` also complains about invalid types:

```
➜ mypy test.py 
test.py:25: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
```

The purpose of `typing` module is to allow third party tools to perform static checking of your code. There is no magic here - all types are ignored at runtime.

Comment: Then what's the point of `@overload` if we're anyway going to check the types?
EDIT: No point. Got it.

Comment: The reason for my doubt was one of the Pycon talks where the speaker did exactly what's mentioned in the question. Weird.

Comment: @saruftw Please check updated answer. In short - the point of the `typing` module (and in `@overload` in particular) is to allow 3rd party tools (e.g. mypy) to run static checks

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Why not just use `Union[str, int]` to note that the function can get either an int or an str?

Comment: There are 2 overloads in the second example: `(int) -> int` and `(str) -> str`, this cannot be done with `Union`

Answer (score 7):

```
# tested in Python 3.8.5 32-bit
# overloads the method
# imports libraries from the base distribution 
# confuses some linters
# undermines type-hinting by documenting *kwargs or dispatch signature

from functools import singledispatch

class Car:
    def __init__(self, color: str, brand: str) -> None:
        self.color = color
        self.brand = brand


@singledispatch
def describe_car(color: str, kind: str) -> str:
    return "Little " + color + " " + kind

@describe_car.register(Car)
def _(car: Car) -> str:
        return describe_car(car.color, car.brand)


newcar = Car("red", "corvette")

print(describe_car("green", "pinto"))
print(describe_car(newcar))
```

pythonout>
Little green pinto
Little red corvette