# How to properly overload on bool for 3 different cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, typing

I am writing my own `run` function. How to write 3rd overload on dynamic value `bool` for `text`, so that it doesn't conflict with overload for `Literal[False]` and `Literal[True]`?

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Optional, Literal, Union

T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)

# If text is empty or false, input has to be bytes, we are returning bytes.
@overload
def run(text: Literal[False] = False, input: Optional[bytes] = ...) -> bytes: ...
# If text is true, input is str, returning str
@overload
def run(text: Literal[True], input: Optional[str] = ...) -> str: ...
# When we do not know what is text, it can be anything, but has to be the same.
#@overload
#def run(text: bool, input: Optional[Union[str, bytes]] = ...) -> Union[str, bytes]: ...
#def run(text: bool, input: Optional[T] = ...) -> T: ...


def run(text: bool = False, input: Optional[Union[str, bytes]] = None) -> Union[str, bytes]: return ""

run(input="")  # error
run(input=b"")  # ok
run(False, "")  # error
run(False, b"")  # ok
run(True, "")  # ok
run(True, b"")  # error
def test() -> bool: ...
run(test(), "")  # ok
run(test(), b"")  # ok
```

[pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.349&pythonVersion=3.12&pythonPlatform=Linux&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChRIokBPXLUgc2zwJEAKpzQA1YiAA0UMADc0IADZhiAExkB5XDTrElMgDJYki-TICqpWqUaMhUALxQRucZIAUAciFeZ9JGkoACN2U3oASjsAYigASWA2NAAPIix6KDQ8DlkQKGB9ejQZblxkKAALYgykMBC0ELC0ehkAdwbJBvQUEGteRvCAOkYAAXlFFXVGNTREkARSD1NUgC4oY1MQfQBtADFCtABdJyh9pSKS0jKkNe1dUh3Q8OPnQbeIqABaAD4B5rW3sNYgkkqlsDV5sVsFdyukoAEgt1UH0%2BAjRuNlKo1NNZlB5otljd1iYzEptkJIYdLtdbjobDsES8oICPj94YEAW9GLEAOoVNCkKDtKBqOoUIgAaworSFVTSNRSSBKRAAxmR6iRSGEKtweDJguUqjU6sEGkh%2BfDiBA0ECxgpMVNojM5gsloq1sEwGADNCaVA7vSyVYbNsEfqmvRDkyWV9fsG6KHAuHnpzhjiXQT3SEvUoTmcLr7kLT7jt46RE0Ens0oycAHJ0NCsuPWBNhv6RtZI3pQABEPbs%2BI8pWQjj7HygsUU4BAjEHw6QjmCY6gE9kEtnrvzUOXq6nBA3iy3%2Bp3sTA68HFIQ25749P59dl6hS5vK8nIGn6aSAQ8Tez3tTB5ut%2BEQyCea6AeESA-seL6rmejBAA) .

When the 3rd overload is uncommented, all forms are valid. Is it possible for the 3rd form not to be "catch it all"?

Comment: What is your question exactly ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: It seems it's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034965/5168011

Comment: Hi @Maaddy! `What is your question exactly ?` Sorry if it is unclear. My question is how to write the overload for a function similar to  `subprocess.run`, that the usages of the function are properly type checked. `what are you trying to achieve ?` I have my own implementation of `run` function based on websockets using Nomad orchestrator. I want to properly type annotate it in python.

Comment: Excellent question. No, this is impossible. The best way I know is to use `Never` return trying to prohibit every non-conformant signature, but you'll only get `unreachable` warnings on **next** line if it exists, nothing if it does not, and you also need `--warn-unreachable` enabled for that. You can check that approach in [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=30231229c8495e58a11b8c4accae44bc).

Comment: Would you mind me mailing code from your question to typing-sig? I would like to suggest to special-case `Never` usage in `overload`ed definitions in arguments, so that the following may work: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=088e43911f5a0c1b975ea3a67d8e70bc In previous playground, comment out errors one-by-one to see what works and what fails, you get only one error at a time, since all code below is unreachable and thus not checked.

Comment: (`s/Never/NoReturn/` for python between 3.6 and 3.10 incl.)

Comment: Hi. `Would you mind me mailing code` I don't mind. Code on stackoverflow is under CC BY-SA, feel free doing anything ;)

Comment: Could you proof read your title again? Something is not quite right.

Comment: Would you consider changing the function to `def run(input: AnyStr) -> AnyStr`, and passing `cast(str, None)` or `cast(bytes, None)` as appropriate (instead of a raw `None` value) to indicate the correct return type?

Comment: `Would you consider` yea, but that is really unpleasant to do in case of no `input`. Another really simple solution is just to make two type checked functions `run_bytes()` and `run_text()` that call `run()` and `run()` just has no type checking.