# Overloading without classes

Tags: python, polymorphism, overloading

How can I write multiple functions in python with the same name and a different number of arguments so that function execution is decided by the number of arguments?
I am having an error in executing the following program in Python

```py
def area(r):
  a=3.14*r*r
  return a
def area(l,b):
  a=l*b
  return a
print(area(710))
print(area(6,2))
```

Comment: `def area(x, y=None):`? In the general case this is "multiple dispatch", and you can use libraries like https://pythonhosted.org/multidispatch/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use method overloading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202938/how-do-i-use-method-overloading-in-python)

Comment: What you are trying to say is to some extent different than what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

In python function overloading is done by providing default values for the parameters
For Instance what you can do here is provide a default value for the parameter b (maybe 'None'), and change the rest of the function accordingly

```
def area(a, b=None):
    if b:
        ans = a*b
    else:
        ans = (a*a)*3.14
    return ans
```

This function can work if you provide it 2 parameters, the output will be the area of rectangle, or if you give it only parameter to work with it will give back the area of a circle

Comment: The program which I wrote, I saw it on Unacademy. It was written by one of its teachers'.It worked for her but when I used it for me it showed an error. Can you please explain do I execute the program which I mentioned?

Comment: "It worked for her" - can't reproduce.

Comment: If I have understood your problem properly, now you just need to call this function like this `print(area(720))` or `print(area(6,2))` that should print the answer for either 1 or 2 parameters. Correct me if you meant something else

Comment: https://unacademy.com/lesson/function-overloading-in-python-polymorphism/H11OHJJY.This is the link of the video which I saw.The program is between 1:44 and 3:05

Comment: @Ash I just checked what you were saying, and I also felt it should work, but it gives a **TypeError** for me too. I can't tell you why its not working, but I think the method I showed you here, is a better choice for overloading in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a use case for unpacking.

```py
def area(*values):
    if len(values) == 1:
        r = values[0]
        return 3.14 * r ** 2
    if len(values) == 2:
        l, b = values
        return l * b
    raise ValueError("Takes only one or two arguments.")
```

In this example, the two asterisks indicates that `values` will take *all* positional arguments passed to `area`. So, if you call `area(1)`, `values` will be `[1]`, if you call `area(1, 2, 3, 4)`, `values` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, *etc*. So you can check the number of arguments passed to the function by checking the length of the list. However, be careful not to overuse it, it can make code a bit confusing...