# How to do function overloading in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, decorator, python-decorators

I want to implement function overloading in Python. I know by default Python does not support overloading. That is what I am asking this question.

I have the following code:

```py
def parse():
    results = doSomething()  
    return results
```

```py
x = namedtuple('x',"a b c")

def parse(query: str, data: list[x]):
    results = doSomethingElse(query, data)
    return results
```

The only solution I can think of is to check the arguments:

```py
def parse(query: str, data: list[x]):
    if query is None and data is None:
       results = doSomething()  
       return results 
    else:
       results = doSomethingElse(query, data)   
       return results
```

Is it possible to do function overloading in Python like in Java (i.e. with out the branching)?

Is there is a clear way using a decorator or some library?

Comment: Python does not support overloading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use method overloading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202938/how-do-i-use-method-overloading-in-python)

Comment: There's no overloading in Python. You could fiddle something together with decorators but in general: if you learn a new language use it as it is intended to use. Don't try to use it like the languages you already know.

Comment: However, there are libraries, e.g. `multimethod` that hide the branching for you

Comment: What you already have is the second-best way to do it. The best way to do it is: don't.

Comment: In most cases, overloading is an attempt to gloss over the fact that you should have defined two separate functions in the first place. The programmer who has to decide which arguments to pass to `parse` could just as easily decide whether to call `parse_nothing()` or `pass_something("foo", [1,2,3])` instead.

Answer (score 8):

There is the [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) decorator used for properly annotating a callable with two or more distinct call signatures. But it still requires exactly one actual implementation. The usage would be as follows:

```py
from typing import overload


@overload
def parse(query: None = None, data: None = None) -> None:
    ...


@overload
def parse(query: str, data: list[object]) -> None:
    ...


def parse(query: str | None = None, data: list[object] | None = None) -> None:
    if query is None and data is None:
        print("something")
    else:
        print(f"something else with {query=} and {data=}")


parse()            # something
parse("foo", [1])  # something else with query='foo' and data=[1]
```

Note that the ellipses `...` are meant literally, i.e. that is all that should be in the "body" of that function overload.

That is how it is done in Python. As mentioned in the comments already, there is no syntax for literally writing overloaded function implementations. If you write two implementations, the last one will simply override the first.

Even if you *could* build something like that with syntactically pleasing decorators, I would probably advise against it because it will likely confuse everyone else since it is not how Python was designed. Also, if you have a lot of complex overloads that all require different implementation logic, I would argue this is *probably* just bad design. And if the branches are clear/simple as in your example, then I see no problem with having them in one function body.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this using `singledispatch` of the standard library `functools`. [functools.singledispath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to learn more.

Your example assuming you are returning list[x] from the function i.e. `results`:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def parse(query, data: list[x]) -> list[x]:
    return []

@parse.register
def _(query: str, data: list[x]) -> list[x]:
    results = doSomethingElse(query, data)
    return results

@parse.register
def _(query: list[str], data: list[x]) -> list[x]:
    results = doSomethingElseWithListOfStr(query, data)
    return results
```

You can `register` as many of these as long as the return type is the same for the overloaded function. `parse.register` has the format `functionname.register`. So if you defined a `foo` function that needs overloading, you will register it as `foo.register`