# How to use methodoverloading in python?

Tags: python

The class having methods that are the same name with different arguments

```
class greeting:
    def sayhello(self,name=None,add=None):
        if name is not None and add is not None:
            print("Hello"+name+add)
        elif name is not None and add is None:
            print("Hello"+name)
        else:
            print("None")
c1=greeting()
c1.sayhello("Python","23")
c1.sayhello("Python")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use method overloading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202938/how-do-i-use-method-overloading-in-python)