# Can I have two sets of arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, dice

I am trying to make a dice roller in python.
the code is:

```py
class die:
    def __init__(self, num:int, die:int | str, mod:int=0, keep:int=None):
        keep = keep if keep != None else num
        if keep > num:  keep = num
        self.num, self.die, self.mod, self.keep = num, die, mod, keep
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        mod = f"+{self.mod}" if self.mod > 0 else f"-{abs(self.mod)}" if self.mod < 0 else ''
        keep = f"{f"{self.keep}kh" if self.keep > 0 else f"{abs(self.keep)}kl" if self.keep < 0 else ''}"
        return f"{keep}{self.num}d{self.die}{mod}"
    def roll(self) -> int:
        log = []
        die = range(0, self.num)
        for _ in die:
            log += [rand.randint(0, (10 if self.die == '%' else int(self.die)) * (10 if self.die == '%' else 1))]
        if self.keep > 0:
            log = [log] + [heapq.nlargest(self.keep, log)]
        elif self.keep < 0:
            log = [log] + [heapq.nsmallest(abs(self.keep), log)]
        final = sum(log[1], self.mod)
        return final
#Sorry if my code is hard to read.
```

I want to add the ability to pass a dice expression (example: `4d6+3`) as well as individual options. is there any way I can pass a separate argument if there is only one argument provided. For example:

```py
def __init__(self, num:int, die:int | str, mod:int=0, keep:int=None OR expression:str)
```

Comment: I'd personally create classmethod, something like `die.from_expression(exression: str) -> die` and leave the constructor as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202938/how-do-i-use-method-overloading-in-python

Comment: I would put `expression:str=""` as another arguments in `__init__` and I would check if `expression` is not empty - to use other values.

Answer (score 3):

`__init__` is fine the way it is. The job of parsing a string into suitable arguments should be handled by a *class* method.

Something like

```
class die:
    def __init__(self, num:int, die:int | str, mod:int=0, keep:int=None):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_description(cls, descr: str) -> die:
        num, die, mod = re.match("\d+d\d+\+\d+").groups()
        return cls(num, die, mod)

d = die.from_description("4d6+3")
```

Comment: VScode says `re is not defined`. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but `cls` is the same as `self` correct? Also can you explain what is happening in this code?

Comment: `re` must, of course, be imported. `cls` is a conventional name for the first argument to a class method, just as `self` is the conventional name for the first argument of an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring functions with the same name but different parameters is called overloading in other programming languages such as C++ and Java, but Python has only very limited support for the concept through [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) and [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload), neither of which allows functions with distinctly different signatures and separate implementations to share the same name, which is what you're trying to do here.

With type annotations introduced in Python 3.5, it is possible to implement true overloading with a metaclass, as demonstrated in the [`MultiMeta`](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/6e46b78e5644b3e5bf7426d900e2203b7cc630da/src/9/multiple_dispatch_with_function_annotations/example1.py#L75C7-L75C19) recipe included in the [*Python Cookbook*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/) written by David Beazley, where he uses the `__prepare__` method of a metaclass to allow methods of the same name to be stored in a `MultiMethod` instance in a dict subclass that detects name collisions.

David's implementation uses simple type equivalence in matching arguments against method signatures, however, and does not support composite type annotations such as `int | str` as a result, so I refactored his code with the runtime type checker [`typeguard`](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) by decorating methods with [`typeguard.typechecked`](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-the-decorator) to validate arguments against signatures of each overloaded method:

```
import types
from typeguard import typechecked

class MultiMethod:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._methods = []
        self.__name__ = name

    def register(self, method):
        self._methods.append(typechecked(method))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for method in self._methods:
            try:
                return method(*args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        raise TypeError('No matching method')

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)
        return self

class MultiDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            current_value = self[key]
            if isinstance(current_value, MultiMethod):
                current_value.register(value)
            else:
                mvalue = MultiMethod(key)
                mvalue.register(current_value)
                mvalue.register(value)
                super().__setitem__(key, mvalue)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

class Overloadable(type):    
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, clsname, bases):
        return MultiDict()
```

so that:

```
import re

class die(metaclass=Overloadable):
    def __init__(self, num: int, die: int | str, mod: int = 0):
        self.num = num
        self.die = die
        self.mod = mod

    def __init__(self, expr: str):
        self.__init__(*map(int, re.match(r'(\d+)d(\d+)\+(\d+)', expr).groups()))

print(vars(die('4d6+3')))
```

outputs:

```
{'num': 4, 'die': 6, 'mod': 3}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/SnoopyArcticMicrostation