# Python metaclasses: Why isn't __setattr__ called for attributes set during class definition?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have the following python code:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print name, value
        return super(FooMeta, self).__setattr__(name, value)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
    FOO = 123
    def a(self):
        pass
```

I would have expected `__setattr__` of the meta class being called for both `FOO` and `a`. However, it is not called at all. When I assign something to `Foo.whatever` after the class has been defined the method *is* called.

What's the reason for this behaviour and is there a way to intercept the assignments that happen during the creation of the class? Using `attrs` in `__new__` won't work since I'd like to [check if a method is being redefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10761988/298479).

Comment: this exact issue is the reason why metaclass syntax has changed in py3!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A class block is roughly syntactic sugar for building a dictionary, and then invoking a metaclass to build the class object.

This:

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
    FOO = 123
    def a(self):
        pass
```

Comes out pretty much as if you'd written:

```
d = {}
d['__metaclass__'] = FooMeta
d['FOO'] = 123
def a(self):
    pass
d['a'] = a
Foo = d.get('__metaclass__', type)('Foo', (object,), d)
```

Only without the namespace pollution (and in reality there's also a search through all the bases to determine the metaclass, or whether there's a metaclass conflict, but I'm ignoring that here).

The metaclass' `__setattr__` can control what happens when you try to set an attribute on one of its instances (the class object), but **inside the class block** you're not doing that, you're inserting into a dictionary object, so the `dict` class controls what's going on, not your metaclass. So you're out of luck.

---

Unless you're using Python 3.x! In Python 3.x you can define a `__prepare__` classmethod (or staticmethod) on a metaclass, which controls what object is used to accumulate attributes set within a class block before they're passed to the metaclass constructor. The default `__prepare__` simply returns a normal dictionary, but you could build a custom dict-like class that doesn't allow keys to be redefined, and use that to accumulate your attributes:

```
from collections import MutableMapping


class SingleAssignDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._d:
            raise ValueError(
                'Key {!r} already exists in SingleAssignDict'.format(key)
            )
        else:
            self._d[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._d

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r})'.format(type(self).__name__, self._d)


class RedefBlocker(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases, **kwargs):
        return SingleAssignDict()

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, sad):
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, dict(sad))


class Okay(metaclass=RedefBlocker):
    a = 1
    b = 2


class Boom(metaclass=RedefBlocker):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    a = 3
```

Running this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/redef.py", line 50, in <module>
    class Boom(metaclass=RedefBlocker):
  File "/tmp/redef.py", line 53, in Boom
    a = 3
  File "/tmp/redef.py", line 15, in __setitem__
    'Key {!r} already exists in SingleAssignDict'.format(key)
ValueError: Key 'a' already exists in SingleAssignDict
```

Some notes:

1. `__prepare__` has to be a `classmethod` or `staticmethod`, because it's being called before the metaclass' instance (your class) exists.
2. `type` still needs its third parameter to be a real `dict`, so you have to have a `__new__` method that converts the `SingleAssignDict` to a normal one
3. I could have subclassed `dict`, which would probably have avoided (2), but I really dislike doing that because of how the non-basic methods like `update` don't respect your overrides of the basic methods like `__setitem__`. So I prefer to subclass `collections.MutableMapping` and wrap a dictionary.
4. The actual `Okay.__dict__` object is a normal dictionary, because it was set by `type` and `type` is finicky about the kind of dictionary it wants. This means that overwriting class attributes after class creation does not raise an exception. You can overwrite the `__dict__` attribute after the superclass call in `__new__` if you want to maintain the no-overwriting forced by the class object's dictionary.

---

Sadly this technique is unavailable in Python 2.x (I checked). The `__prepare__` method isn't invoked, which makes sense as in Python 2.x the metaclass is determined by the `__metaclass__` magic attribute rather than a special keyword in the classblock; which means the dict object used to accumulate attributes for the class block already exists by the time the metaclass is known.

Compare Python 2:

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
    FOO = 123
    def a(self):
        pass
```

Being roughly equivalent to:

```
d = {}
d['__metaclass__'] = FooMeta
d['FOO'] = 123
def a(self):
    pass
d['a'] = a
Foo = d.get('__metaclass__', type)('Foo', (object,), d)
```

Where the metaclass to invoke is determined from the dictionary, versus Python 3:

```
class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    FOO = 123
    def a(self):
        pass
```

Being roughly equivalent to:

```
d = FooMeta.__prepare__('Foo', ())
d['Foo'] = 123
def a(self):
    pass
d['a'] = a
Foo = FooMeta('Foo', (), d)
```

Where the dictionary to use is determined from the metaclass.

Answer (score 7):

There are no assignments happening during the creation of the class. Or: they are happening, but not in the context you think they are. All class attributes are collected from class body scope and passed to metaclass' `__new__`, as the last argument:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        print attrs
        return type.__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
    FOO = 123
```

Reason: when the code in the class body executes, there's no class yet. Which means there's no opportunity for metaclass to intercept anything *yet*.

Answer (score 2):

Class attributes are passed to the metaclass as a single dictionary and my hypothesis is that this is used to update the `__dict__` attribute of the class all at once, e.g. something like  `cls.__dict__.update(dct)` rather than doing `setattr()` on each item.  More to the point, it's all handled in C-land and simply wasn't written to call a custom `__setattr__()`.

It's easy enough to do whatever you want to the attributes of the class in your metaclass's `__init__()` method, since you're passed the class namespace as a `dict`, so just do that.

Answer (score 0):

During the class creation, your namespace is evaluated to a dict and passed as an argument to the metaclass, together with the class name and base classes. Because of that, assigning a class attribute inside the class definition wouldn't work the way you expect. It doesn't create an empty class and assign everything. You also can't have duplicated keys in a dict, so during class creation attributes are already deduplicated. Only by setting an attribute after the class definition you can trigger your custom __setattr__.

Because the namespace is a dict, there's no way for you to check duplicated methods, as suggested by your other question. The only practical way to do that is parsing the source code.