# Same function names in python , No error?

Tags: python, function, nested, overloading, overriding

To be honest, I was expecting some sort of error, like '**you can't rename two nested functions with same name in a same body like that'** , Can we define any number of functions with same name in python ?

```
In [40]: def add(i,j):
   ....:     def add(i,j):
   ....:         print i+j
   ....:     def add(i,j):    
   ....:         print i-j
   ....:     return add(i,j)
   ....: 

In [41]: add(5,4)
1
```

**Is this Overloading of function, or Overriding of function ??**

Comment: NO, the last function definition of the same name will override/overwrite all the above definitions

Comment: umm , U sure I think its overloading ? not overriding

Comment: overloading is not supported in python

Comment: Rules of overloading specify `The overloaded function must differ either by the arity or data types`, since there are no types of arguments in function definition.. no overloading,,, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733264/function-overloading-in-python-missing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. A `def` statement is functionally an assignment (of the function to the name), and you can have any number of assignments to the same name. (It`s important to realize that function definitions are *executed* in Python, they are not statically evaluated at compile time.)

There are hacky ways to catch this in class definitions, such as [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761988/how-can-i-detect-duplicate-method-names-in-a-python-class/10762966#10762966) I posted in May. If you're using Python 3, there's a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762088/python-metaclasses-why-isnt-setattr-called-for-attributes-set-during-class/10763270#10763270).

For functions, that won't work, so I believe you're stuck with this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Defining a function is like like assigning a value to a variable.  You can do this in Python:

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

Likewise you can do this:

```
def f():
    return 1
def f():
    return 2
```

In both cases, the last value specified overwrites any previous values.  So the last one wins.

The fact that it's a nested function has no bearing on the issue.  The same applies in any context.

Answer (score 0):

the last functions overwrites the others... so, there's no error! :)

Answer (score 0):

A function definition introduces the function name in the current symbol table. The value of the function name has a type that is recognized by the interpreter as a user-defined function. This value can then be assigned to another name, or even reassigned by redefining the function.

In cases where a function is redefined, the latest definition will be used as it is the one that is recognized by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the second nested `add()` overwrites the first, but the outer one remains unchanged.

Here is a minimal example:

```
def do_sth(s):
    def do_sth(s):
        print('Hello, %s!' % s)
    print('Ola')
    do_sth(s)

>>> do_sth('chuinul')
Ola
Hello, chuinul!
>>> do_sth('chuinul')
Ola
Hello, chuinul!
```

When you call `do_sth()` the second time, this is still the outer function you defined that is being called. Otherwise you would have only had:

```
>>> do_sth('chuinul')
Hello, chuinul!
```