# How does __setattr__ and __getattribute__ interact in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age
    def __getattribute__(self,attribute):
        print("Initializing getattribute")
        return 6
    def __setattr__(self,attribute,value):
        print("Initializing setattr")
        return object.__setattr__(self,attribute,value)
test=Test(4)
test.age
print(test.age)
```

From the code above the result is :

```
Initializing setattr
Initializing getattribute
Initializing getattribute
6
```

I understand where each dunder method is called, but what  do they really do?In the previous example getattribute dictate the attribute value and if I delete the line :

`return object.__setattr__(self,attribute,value)`

Nothing changes.

So what does `__setattr__` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python metaclasses: Why isn't \_\_setattr\_\_ called for attributes set during class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762088/python-metaclasses-why-isnt-setattr-called-for-attributes-set-during-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__getattribute__` is called before any other attempt is made to access an attribute. No matter what `__setattr__` does, `test.age` is handled by `test.__getattribute__("age")`, which returns `6` whether or not there is an attribute named `age`.

If you get rid of `__getattribute__`:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age
    def __setattr__(self,attribute,value):
        print("Initializing setattr")
        return object.__setattr__(self,attribute,value)

test=Test(4)
test.age
print(test.age)
```

The class behaves normally, setting `test.age` to 4. If you further get rid of the call to `object.__setattr__`, then you'll get an `AttributeError` because `self.age = age` will never actually create or set the `age` attribute; it just prints the initialization message and returns:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age
    def __setattr__(self,attribute,value):
        print("Initializing setattr")

test=Test(4)
test.age
print(test.age)
```

results in

```
Initializing setattr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chepner/tmp.py", line 11, in <module>
    test.age
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'age'
```