# Am I using metaclass correctly?

Tags: python, metaclass

I just realised that `__setattr__` doesn't work on the class itself. So this implementation,

```py
class Integer:
    me_is_int = 0

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError
```

doesn't raise on this:

```py
Integer.me_is_int = "lol"
```

So, switching to a metaclass:

```py
class IntegerMeta:
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError

class Integer(metaclass=IntegerMeta):
    me_is_int = 0
```

this works, but this:

```py
Integer().me_is_int = "lol"
```

doesn't work yet again. So do I need to copy the `__setattr__` method in `Integer` again to make it work on instances? Is it not possible for `Integer` to use `IntegerMeta`'s `__setattr__` for instances?

Comment: The metaclass can influence the entire class creating, including adding a default `__setattr__` (say, the one from the metaclass itself). But you have to actually tell it to do so.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763270/7867968) could answer your question?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how can I achieve that, I cannot even find the meaning of the arguments passed to `type.__new__` (i.e. metaclass' `__new__` function signature)

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your reasoning: having a custom `__setattr__` special method in the *metaclass* will affect any value setting on the class, and having the it on the *class* will affect all instances of the class.

With that in mind, if you don't want to duplicate code, is to arrange the metaclass itself to inject the logic in a class, whenever it is created.

The way you've written it, even thinking as an example, is dangerous, as it will affect *any* attribute set on the class or instances - but if you have a list of the attributes you want to guard in that way, it would also work.

```
attributes_to_guard = {"me_is_int",}

class Meta:
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
        # This line itself would not work if the setattr would not check
        # for a restricted set of attributes to guard:
        cls.__setattr__ = cls.__class__.__setattr__
        # Also, note that this overrides any manually customized
        # __setattr__ on the classes. The mechanism to call those, 
        # and still add the guarding logic in the metaclass would be
        # more complicated, but it can be done
        super().__init__(name, bases, ns, **kw)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in attributes_to_guard not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError()

class Integer(metaclass=Meta):
    me_is_int = 0
```

Comment: I think a better way to achieve this (as opposed to having a list of attributes to guard) would be using a descriptor on the metaclass.  No need for custom `__setattr__`.

Comment: So TLDR is, I shouldn't override `__setattr__` for any `Integer` subclasses? Also why didn't you use `__new__` method instead?

Comment: yes - in the example code above, as it is, any `__setattr__` in the classes would be suppressed by the one in the metaclass. You maybe could check "descriptors" on how to control writting to a single attribute without having to mess with `__setattr__`: they might be  better for "everyday use". 
As for `__init__` instead of `__new__`: it is a bit less intrusive: both are called at class creation, but `__init__` in a later stage, when the class actually already exists. As we do with normal classes, we can use `__init__` instead of `__new__` on metaclasses.