# How to get attributes in the order they are declared in a Python class?

Tags: python, metaclass

As described in [PEP435](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/), an `enum` can be defined this way:

```
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

And the resulting `enum members` of `Color` can be iterated in definition order: `Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue`.

This reminds me of `Form` in `Django`, in which fields can be rendered in the order they are declared in a `Form` subclass. They implemented this by maintaining a field counter, every time a new field is instantiated the counter value get incremented.

But in the definition of `Color`, we don't have something like a `FormField`, how can we implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3, you can customize the namespace that a class is declared in with the metaclass. For example, you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class EnumMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcls, cls, bases, d):
        print(d)
        return type.__new__(mcls, cls, bases, d)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcls, cls, bases):
        return OrderedDict()


class Color(metaclass=EnumMeta):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

This prints

```
OrderedDict([('__module__', '__main__'), ('red', 1), ('green', 2), ('blue', 3)])
```

Comment: I wonder if this can be done in Python2.x, so that we make a backport of `enum`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your answer, exactly!

Comment: No. You're reduced to ```FormField```-type hacks there.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x you can use [this horrible hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761988/how-can-i-detect-duplicate-method-names-in-a-python-class/10762966#10762966) I wrote to answer a slightly different question, as a foundation for functionality of this sort. So, really, you can't.  :-)