# List methods of a class but not sorted alphabetically

Tags: python

The [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function return a list of the **methods** but:

> The resulting list is sorted alphabetically

I want to know which ones are but not sorted alphabetically. I use the name to help to understand what does this method. I use name like game_start, game_battle, game_map. I could change the name to start, battle, map but if I want to use the same submit method for all this other methods in a tkinter app. So I need the name of the methods to eval in the  order of declaration.

Is there any other workaround?

example:

```
class hi(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="LLopis"
    def question(self):
        print("Question?")
    def answer(self):
        print("Answer")
```

The result of `dir(hi)` is:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'answer', 'question']
```

I want a function that return instead (or whatever is the internal order of the private methods, but by order of finding):

```
['__init__', 'question', 'answer']
```

Edit: I do not care about attributes like hi.name, therefore although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514286/how-to-get-attributes-in-the-order-they-are-declared-in-a-python-class) is related it is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: The 'internal' order is a *dictionary*, so **not ordered**.

Comment: Why is being sorted alphabetically a problem? Do you want the order in which they occurred in source code? If so, what are you trying to achieve that way?

Comment: I want to use the methods I define in the order I write them inside the class, but I don't want to define a list with the wanted order or change the methods' name.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.3

Comment: I've closed as a certain dupe target... but if anyone can find a better target as I know this has been asked various times (in some form or another)

Comment: @Jon I just want methods so I think it is not a duplicate of attributes declaration sorting

Comment: "I don't want to define a list with the wanted order or change the methods' name." I cannot think of a scenario where this would be a major issue.

Comment: @Llopis okay... I've re-opened but I *know* this has been asked before... (agree though that probably wasn't the best target - apologies)

Comment: @TheSoundDefense It is an exercise, it is not a real scenario, but I do not want to change the method from game_* to game_a*, game_b*. Jon I would be glad to know where or how, if you remember or find it let me know please.

Comment: Start with the example from the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation - then filter out callables either using `inspect.ismethod` or `callable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically to CPython, you can utilize the `fistrlineno` property:

```
fns = []
for p in dir(hi):
    a = getattr(hi, p)
    if hasattr(a, '__code__'):
        fns.append((a.__code__.co_firstlineno, p))


print([x[1] for x in sorted(fns)])  # ['__init__', 'question', 'answer']
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand the co_firstlineno property. I found that is the first line (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) of a definition, but in the python-dev there is some discussion about it in 2010: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-August/102735.html. Do you have a clear idea of how to use it?

Comment: From my understanding, that thread is about decorated functions and returning exact line numbers. For your problem, only relative position is important, so what exactly does `firstlineno` return doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 3):

When executing a program, the interpreter (CPython) does not preserve the order in which a class's methods got declared, so there's no way to find that out at runtime other than by looking at the source code.

P.S. But see a remark by @Jon Clements in the comments below.

Comment: Not exactly true - if the OP is using Python 3.x, `__prepare__` with a metaclass can be used to return a custom dictionary (such as an `OrderedDict`) - there are hack-arounds in 2.x also available

Comment: @JonClements: Fair enough. I'll add a remark pointing to this comment of yours. :-)

Comment: @JonClements: BTW, feel free to write up a better answer. I'd be happy to upvote that and delete mine as it's clearly half-baked.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the source code (accessed with `inspect`) yourself to an abstract syntax tree (AST) and then list the method names:

```
import ast, inspect
codeobj = compile(inspect.getsource(hi), "<string>", "exec", flags=ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
methods = [_.name for _ in codeobj.body[0].body]
print(methods) # ['__init__', 'question', 'answer']
```

This only works if you save the code to a file, not in the IDLE, but I assume that you are doing this anyway.

[image: example run on my computer]