# Is it legal to define two methods with the same name but different returning types?

Tags: python

I've written a piece of code to determine a typical palindrome string. I did this by the definition of a reverse() method returning a string. I am also eager to have the same method, but in the void form, because of some future needs.

As I add the latter to the code, the valid output will become invalid. Is it legal to define two methods with the same name, but different returning types?

If not, how can I write this code with the void-type method?

```
class detector(object):
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string

    forbidden = (' ','!','?','.','-','_','&','%',"#",",")

    def eliminator(self):
        for item in self.forbidden:
            if item in self.string:
                self.string = self.string.replace(item,"")

    def reverse(self):
        return self.string[::-1]

    #def reverse(self):
    #    self.string = self.string[::-1]    I am prone to add this method

    def check(self):
        reversed = self.reverse()
        if self.string == reversed:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")

det = detector("rise to vote, sir!")
det.eliminator()
det.check()
```

When I add the outcommented lines, the valid "Yes" becomes "No"!

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[How can I detect duplicate method names in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761988)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, if you define a second method in a class, the second definition overwrites the first one and all that will be left is the second one.

However, you can have a function and a method with the same name. Try this:

```
def reverse(detector_object):
    return detector(detector_object.string[::-1])

class detector(object):
...
    def reverse(self):
        self.string = self.string[::-1]
```

Now you have a function called `reverse` and a method called `reverse`, and you would use them like `sorted` and `sort` for lists:

```
old_detector.reverse() # reverse it in place
new_detector = reverse(old_detector) # return a new detector object with the string reversed
```

Compare this to sorting a list:

```
my_list.sort() # sort list in place
new_list = sorted(my_list)
```

Seeing as this mirrors a built-in strategy, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: The built-in strategy would be to have `reverse()` to do in-place editing and `reversed()` return a reversed copy.

Comment: @Rob Watts:The answer sounds amazing... As a matter of fact, I am overwhelmed with the difference of "method" and "function", as you illustrated above. Because, I thought there are both the same concepts...

Comment: @matinking They're similar. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method) is a StackOverflow question talking about the difference. Basically, methods are attached to a class or instance, and functions are not.

Comment: @Rob Watts: You're considerably right. Appreciated due to your guidance.

Answer (score 5):

If you call two methods, Python will override the first one made, leaving just the second one defined:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 1
...
>>> def foo():
...     return 2
...
>>> foo()
2
>>>
```

Basically, the second one *overrides* the first.

**To see why *Python* would do this, take it from a common sense standpoint**. Say you have a homework assignment, which is online, and when you get to it, there are **two** assignments under the same name. How would you know which one to pick? Basically, *Python* just picks the most recent one, which is the smart choice.

Also, **when calling the function**, how do *you* think Python would understand which one you want if they both have the same name?

Python may be a smart language, but it is by no means psychic :)

Comment: To say that Python doesn't know which one to pick at the time you *call* it is misleading.  By the time you call it, there is no choice to be made.  At the time you make the second definition, the first one is overwritten and there is no way to get it back or make use of it.  It's not just that the one defined last is the one called; rather, the one defined last is the only one that even exists to be called.

Comment: @ aj8uppal: Thank you. Assume that I rename the second method. Would you guiding me to solve the solution by the void method.
Mine is by the string-type one...!

Comment: @matinking what exactly do you mean by *solving the solution?*

Comment: @ aj8uppal: I got the output with the above code. I need the valid output with utilization of the commented method, instead of my string-type function.

Answer (score 5):

It is legal to write that, but it doesn't define two methods.  The last definition overwrites the first, so only the last one exists and that one will always be called.  It is the same as if you did

```
x = 1
x = 2
```

The first assignment is obliterated by the second.

As for your larger question: The way to have two methods that return different things is to define two methods with different names.  Python does not know anything about the types that a function "intends" to return.  There is no such thing as a "void-type method".

Answer (score 2):

No. Python [does *not* have method/function *overloading*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading), which is a prerequisite for such a discriminating operation (at the invocation level), which in turn allows "two methods with the same name".

In languages with overloading, which are most often statically typed, it is generally prohibited for the return type to be the sole discriminator or even differ - doing so would require the *usage* of the resulting expression to be taken into account.

As far as this particular problem, I would simply *not include* the "void form". If such a case is needed, make it a distinct method (with a unique name per above restrictions) that makes it apparent that the goal is merely a side-effect without a usable result: for instance, compare the name of `sorted` with `list.sort`.

Comment: Thank you for the coherent clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not legal; how would Python know which one to call?  Just rename one of the methods.

Comment: Actually I am going to use such naming system just like the overloading concept, corresponding to the other OOP languages, where the names are the same.Furthermore, I have no idea how to refine the code within the utilization of the void-type function!

Comment: @matinking: Most OOP languages do not support overloading on return type; most only support overloading on the arguments, if at all.

Comment: @jwodder: So mean that overloading on return type is impossible, right?!

Comment: Not impossible, but the benefits usually outweigh the downsides in designing such a language. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type, it seems at least Perl and Haskell support it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by subclassing:

```
class detector(object):
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string
    def reverse(self):
        return self.string[::-1]

class weirdo(detector):
    def reverse(self):
        self.string = self.string[::-1]
        return self.string
```

Now if you instantiate `x = weirdo('hey')` its behavior will be to permanently reverse its string value each time you call `x.reverse()` whereas objects of class `detector` will continue to work as before.

(I made `weirdo.reverse()` also return the new value, so that calling code can always use objects of either type.)

I'm not particularly recommending this, just demonstrating an approach. This would prooerly belong in a comment, but comments can't really contain code on StackOverflow.

Comment: You resolve the case within two different classes. The case needed to be considered just under operation of one class, actually.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you have a constraint like that? This is one of the main reasons to have classes -- the caller doesn't need to know the precise type of the object, just trust that it implements the method we call in a manner suitable for this object.

Comment: But as noted in another comment of mine, the simple fix is to have `reverse` and `reversed` just like Pyrhon has `sort` and `sorted`. That's actually what I would recommend.

Comment: The resolved approach might be considered as utilization of a function and a method, are which named the same. This approach in essential in the case that one operation, as a bounded method, is responsible for computing some stuff and return the final value. But in view of the effective coding in large projects, one might need to  have the same functionality for some vast kind of objects. In this case, she puts the function one in that class in order to keep both similar functionalities, are which realized with the method and the function, in a unique place together. Otherwise, you're right.