# How to extend or monkey-patch a built-in module

Tags: python

I want to write a custom json module for my team,

First I created a 'json.py' file under the folder(namespace) 'dqa_fileio/config'

so when others want to use my module, it should be called by `import dqa_fileio.config.json`

Then, I want to creates a `read_file` method to load a json file

But I got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'`

I think that because the `file_name` is called json.py,

But I want to keep the filename, is there anyway like Ruby that I can open a class to extend it's ability ? But it seems the `json` is a folder(namespace) not a class ? Please correct me if any wrong concept. Thanks

### json.py (under the namespace dqa_fileio/config)

```
import json 

class Json(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def read_file(self, file_name):
        return json.load(open(file_name, 'r'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Json().read_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: You never defined read_from_json_file() You only defined read_file()

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because how do you think python is supposed to know which one to choose?

You **have** to pick a different name, as long as you want `import json` to import the correct module.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707644/is-it-legal-to-define-two-methods-with-the-same-name-but-different-returning-typ/23707683#23707683) for more information on the same type of question.

Answer (score 1):

The only other thing I would suggest is to use a package.

Put your `json.py` module in some kind of package.

e.g:

```
common
|-__init__.py
|-json.py
```

Put `common` in your `PYTHONPATH` and/or package it up nicely with an appropriate `setup.py` which your team can install and use in their projects.

Then import it like:

```
from common import json
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Actually, I put me file under a certain namespace, please see my updates, thanks

Comment: I think you should ask a new/different question to avoid this one getting confusing. What you're now sort-of asking is how to "monkey-patch" standard python library modules/functions/classes. Which you can.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python thinks import json is just importing itself, and your class has no load method. The only way to get around this is to change your file name, or use some very unpythonic circular imports.