# Two functions with the same name in Python

Tags: python

I was just playing around with Python and realized something weird.

I have the below function:

```
def myfun():    #f1
    return 1
def myfun():    #f2
    return 0

print (myfun())
```

I changed the values in `f1` and `f2`, but still it always seems to be printing the return value of `f2`. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: second function overwrites the first one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you pls explain?

Comment: I can't understand what you are expecting to happen here, and how that differs from what you actually see.

Comment: The issue is obvious for us "scripters", but indeed weird enough for someone with compiled langs background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In compiled languages you would generally get an error message if you try to define two functions with the same name. But in Python functions are first-class objects and they are defined dynamically.

When you define a new function with the same name as a previously defined function, the function name is now bound to the new function object, and the old function object is reclaimed by the garbage collector.

So what happens to your functions is no different to what happens with the simple integer examples posted in the other answers on this page.

Similarly, we can do the same thing with functions defined using the `lambda` mechanism. Eg:

```
>>> myfun=lambda:1; myfun=lambda:0; print(myfun())
0
```

Comment: Is there a way to get an error message? It could be accidental (by mistake) that they have the same name.

Comment: OK, I found something: *[How can I detect duplicate method names in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761988)*

Answer (score 0):

Why is that weird? The second function decleration overrides the first, so by the time `print` is called only `f2` exists.

Comment: that's how the interpreter works. suppose you write `a = 10` and then `a = 20` in the next line. What would you expect the value of a to be after those two lines?

Comment: I think you should study some oops first ... then it will be more understandable to u

Comment: @TusharGupta - what is oops?

Comment: Object Oriented Programming concepts @WeaselFox :P

Answer (score 0):

The second definition causes the name `myfun` to be bound to its function replacing the binding produced by the previous definition. This is exactly the same as what happens in:

```
a = 1
a = 0

print a
```

Comment: weird - the very same example in all three answers. Programmers think alike I guess..

Comment: I was also about to post an example using `a`, too. :)