# How to use Overloading in Iron Python?

Tags: python, overloading, ironpython

I wanted to use overloading in Iron Python but seems it's not working :

```
import sys
import clr

def  af(a, b):
     c = a+b
     print c
     return c
def af(j):
  y = j*j
  print y
  return y

 af(6,7)
 af(5)
```

I get a error =\
Is there any way to use overloading ?
my purpose is to write a function : `foo(doAction,numTimes)`
when by default if I use `foo(action)`: it will do it once,
 or I'll write : `foo(action,6)`

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading in Python: Missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733264/function-overloading-in-python-missing)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113032/overloaded-functions-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronPython might run on the CLR but that doesn't make it C#. In any kind of Python, you can only define a function once. Defining a function is really just assigning to a name, so in your code you assign a function to `af`, then assign another one to the same name, so the first one is simply discarded.

The way to do this in Python is via default arguments:

```
def aj(a, b=None):
    if b is not None:
        result = a + b
    else:
        result = a * a
    print result
    return result
```

For your actual use case of course you can define `numtimes` with a default of 1:

```
def foo(action, numtimes=1):
    # whatever
```