# Python: flexible way to declare constructors

Tags: python, constructor

What is a clean way to declare multiple constructors for one class?

For example, let's say I have an `Item` class.  One way to create an Item (for example is)

```
item = Item(product_id, name, description,price)
```

another way to do the same thing might

```
item = Item(otherItem)
```

And then another way to do this.. maybe in some cases I don't have the price so I want to pass just

```
item = Item(product_id, name,description)
```

and yet another case might be

```
item = Item(product_id,price)
```

---

The other question I have is:
There are some private variables which might be initialized during runtime.
Let's say I have some random variable `itemCount` and I want to keep a track of it internally.

How do I declare it that I dont have to put it in initialization mode, but rather, somewhere in the run time..
I can do something like

```
self._count +=1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use default arguments:

```
class Item(object):

  def __init__(self, product_id = None, name = None, description = None, price = None)
      ... implementation ...
```

You can substitute in any value you want for `None`, if the default value should be something different.

Example usage:

```
item1 = Item(product_id = 4, price = 13) # use the field name!
item2 = Item(name = "hammer", description = "used to belong to Thor")
```

---

For the copy constructor, `item = Item(otherItem)`, @Raymond's suggestions of class methods and factory functions may be the most Pythonic way to go.

---

Update:  [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python) a question about multiple constructors in Python.  It also mentions using `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: Hi.. But in this method.. lets say in initialization i dont want name.. but the description to pass on.. then how would this do that..like Item(123,description).. whether its a name or description?? how wil it figure out

Comment: Guido is strongly opposed to using optional/named parameters in that way. For example, that is why we have both itertools.ifilter() and itertools.ifilterfalse() instead of a single tool with a flag that switches behaviors.  Likewise, the datetime class uses multiple separate constructors (now, from_ordinal, from_timestamp).  If you're going to give advice to other Python programmers, it should match the Python way of doing things.  Having a default argument for price is reasonable if priceless items can be created, but the *otheritem* case of cloning demands a classmethod.

Answer (score 4):

The two most common approaches for providing multiple constructors are:

1. [class methods](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) and
2. [factory functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Here is an [example taken from the standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l194) showing how [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) uses a classmethod to implement *fromkeys()* as an alternate class constructor:

```
@classmethod
def fromkeys(cls, iterable, value=None):
    '''OD.fromkeys(S[, v]) -> New ordered dictionary with keys from S.
    If not specified, the value defaults to None.

    '''
    self = cls()
    for key in iterable:
        self[key] = value
    return self
```

As an example of the other common approach, here's a [factory function used in symtable.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/symtable.py#l19) in the standard library:

```
class SymbolTableFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__memo = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def new(self, table, filename):
        if table.type == _symtable.TYPE_FUNCTION:
            return Function(table, filename)
        if table.type == _symtable.TYPE_CLASS:
            return Class(table, filename)
        return SymbolTable(table, filename)
```

Comment: While you could do this, it seems like optional/named parameters are the more Pythonic way to accomplish the same thing.  There's been very few times where I actually preferred multiple constructors to optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Copying is usually done by a `copy()` method on instances instead of by providing a "copy constructor", so it's

```
item = other_item.copy()
```

instead of

```
item = Item(other_item)
```

All the other constructor signatures you mentioned easily be handled by default arguments and keyword arguments:

```
def __init__(self, product_id, name=None, description=None, price=None):
    ...
```

If you want another constructor with completely different code, than a `classmethod` is the right approach -- see the answer by Raymond Hettinger.