# How to have different input types for the same function?

Tags: python, function, multimethod, generic-function, single-dispatch

The basic idea of what I want to do is:

```
def aFunction(string='', dicti={}):
    if len(str) > 0:
         print('you gave string as input')
    if len(dicti) > 0:
         print('you gave a dict as input')

aFunction(string='test')
dict['test'] = test
aFunction(dicti=dict)
```

I know this kind of idea is possible in more OO type of languages, but is this also possible in Python?

Right now I'm doing

```
def aFunction(input):
    if type(input) == str:
         print('you gave string as input')
    if type(input) == dict:
         print('you gave a dict as input')

aFunction('test')
```

But I want the difference to be clear when the function is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type checks should be avoided in Python (search about ["duck typing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=duck+typing) on that). When they *are* necessary, it should usually be done with `isinstance` rather than an equality check on the type like the question shows. This has the advantage of being more flexible for inheritance situations.

Since [Python 3.4](https://peps.python.org/pep-0443/), the string-like branch and the dict-like branch can be written in separate functions using stdlib [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

So instead of:

```
def aFunction(input_):
    if isinstance(input_, str):
        print('you gave a string-like input')
        ...
    elif isinstance(input_, dict):
        print('you gave a dict-like input')
        ...
```

You can now have:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def aFunction(input_):
    pass

@aFunction.register(str)
def _(input_):
    print("you gave a string-like input")

@aFunction.register(dict)
def _(input_):
    print("you gave a dict-like input")
```

In Python 3.5+ you have another option of using type hinting function annotations. Read [*PEP 484 - Type Hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for more details about that feature. It means the [single dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-single-dispatch) [generic function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generic-function) above can be written as:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def aFunction(input_):
    pass

@aFunction.register
def _(input_: str):
    print("you gave a string-like input")

@aFunction.register
def _(input_: dict):
    print("you gave a dict-like input")
```

Comment: +1 Good point about language philosophy. Plus I believe you should change the name of the `input` argument (now it overwrites a built-in function).

Answer (score 8):

The idea of having the same method support different argument types is known as [multiple dispatch or multimethods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Python).

To get a good introduction to it, you can read this Guido Van Rossum [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Python) and have a look at PyPi since there are a few [multimethod packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=multimethod&submit=search) available.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the name (was looking at polymorphism) that should help

Comment: Nitpick: _multiple dispatch_ is when there are multiple arguments. This is [_single dispatch_](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-single-dispatch).

Answer (score -1):

What you have basically works, there's just some trouble with the variable declarations.  Here is a working vesrion:

```
def aFunction(str = '', dicti = {}):
    if len(str) > 0:
         print 'you gave string as input'
    if len(dicti) > 0:
         print 'you gave a dict as input'

str = 'test'
dicti = dict([('test', 'test')])
aFunction(str = str)
aFunction(dicti = dicti)
aFunction(str = str, dicti = dicti)
aFunction(dicti = dicti, str = str)
```

puts:

```
you gave string as input
you gave a dict as input
you gave string as input
you gave a dict as input
you gave string as input
you gave a dict as input
```

You can also have non-specific arguments that are sent to the function as both a list and a dictionary (see [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python) for example).

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You can still call `aFunction` with: `aFunction([1,2,3])` and it will be assuming that you gave it a string (which clearly isn't the case) as well as `aFunction(dicti="this is not a dict")` and it would assume you inputed a dict. @wim got the correct answer, using duck typing. Assigning a default argument to a given type, won't give you guarantees, since Python is a weakly typed language and it may change at runtime.

Comment: Python is *strongly* typed; you generally cannot substitute a value of one type when a different type is expected. (If Python were weakly typed, then something like `1 + "1"` would equal either `2` or `"11"`, depending on how `+` was defined.) The fact that you can *assign* a value of any type to any name makes it *dynamically* (as opposed to statically) typed.