# Python using classmethod for multiple constructors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been struggling trying to create multiple constructors with the classmethod decorator.  There is an example in SO  - [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)  (second answer)

```
class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self, num_holes=0):
        "defaults to a solid cheese"
        self.number_of_holes = num_holes

    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        return cls(random(100))

    @classmethod
    def slightly_holey(cls):
    return cls(random(33))

    @classmethod
    def very_holey(cls):
        return cls(random(66, 100))
```

However this example is not very clear and the code does not work for me in python 3 when typing the commands given:

```
gouda = Cheese()
emmentaler = Cheese.random()
leerdammer = Cheese.slightly_holey()
```

giving -

```
AttributeError: type object 'Cheese' has no attribute 'random'
```

as this is one of the only examples I can find.

Comment: What are you expecting `random(100)` to do? If you import `random` and replace the calls with `random.randint(0,100)` your code works fine.

Comment: I get: `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`.

Comment: I was expecting a `TypeError` because `random` takes not argument or `NameError` if you didn't import `random` So your code can't produce that error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randint` should work:

```
from random import randint

class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self, num_holes=0):
        "defaults to a solid cheese"
        self.number_of_holes = num_holes

    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        return cls(randint(0, 100))

    @classmethod
    def slightly_holey(cls):
        return cls(randint(0, 33))

    @classmethod
    def very_holey(cls):
        return cls(randint(66, 100))

gouda = Cheese()
emmentaler = Cheese.random()
leerdammer = Cheese.slightly_holey()
```

Now:

```
>>> leerdammer.number_of_holes
11
>>> gouda.number_of_holes
0
>>> emmentaler.number_of_holes
95
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error?  if you try either command: emmentaler = Cheese.random() or leerdammer = Cheese.slightly_holey(), it does not work

Comment: Just copy my solution into a new file and run from the command line.

Comment: @VectorVictor It's not clear what you are doing wrong. This code works.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  My problem goes away if I run the code as file.  However if I paste into Ipython, it doesn't.  I don't understand why exactly, but I don't want to waste more peoples time.  Thanks