# Multiple constructors in python

Tags: python, constructor

How to combine the following 2 classes into one class, Rectangle, so that a Rectangle object can be created either by rect = Rectangle(side_a, side_b) or rect = Rectangle(side_a, area)?

```
class Rectangle1:
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
        self.area = self.side_a * self.side_b

class Rectangle2:
    def __init__(self, side_a, area):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.area = area
        self.side_b = self.area / side_a
```

Comment: The interface you're asking for isn't possible, because there's no way to distinguish whether the second argument is a side length or an area. If creating rectangles from a side length and area is a common task in your use case, you may want to add a `Rectangle.from_side_and_area` static method.

Answer (score 11):

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/3350448).

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """ Create a new rectangle with sides of length a and b.
        """
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
        self.area = self.side_a * self.side_b

    @classmethod
    def from_sides(cls, a, b):
        return cls(a, b)

    @classmethod
    def from_area(cls, a, o):
        return cls(a, o/a)
```

You can then create rectangles as

```
r1 = Rectangle.from_sides(s1, s2)
r2 = Rectangle.from_area(s1, a)
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot overload methods with methods of the same name. Well, you can, but only the last one is then visible.

The other option is [keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) arguments.

With Python 3, you could write:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, side_a, *, side_b=None, area=None):
        self.side_a = side_a
        if side_b is None and area is None:
            raise Exception("Provide either side_b or area")
        if side_b is not None and area is not None:
            raise Exception("Provide either side_b or area, not both")
        if side_b is not None:
            self.side_b = side_b
            self.area = self.side_a * self.side_b
        else:
            self.area = area
            self.side_b = self.area / side_a
```

using `*`  in the middle forces the user to use keyword argument passing from that point, not allowing positionnal, which prevents the mistakes. And the (rather clumsy) manual checking for `None` logic ensures that one and only one keyword parameter is passed to the constructor. The inside is complex, but the interface is safe to use, that's the main point here.

```
r = Rectangle(10,area=20)
r2 = Rectangle(10,side_b=20)
r3 = Rectangle(10,20)   # doesn't run, need keyword arguments
```

Comment: s/ keyword / keyword-only

Comment: The correct term for these arguments is [keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) arguments.

Comment: This is a very neat solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but here's what I came up with:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b = None, area = None):
         self.side_a = side_a
         if area == None:
            self.area = side_a * side_b
            self.side_b = side_b
         else:
            self.side_b = area / side_a
            self.area = area
```

Comment: Like I said abovE: Careful with this. Keyword arguments are still positional and you can legally call this function with neither side_b or area

Comment: marisbest2 - that's a good point, however I like to believe that someone using their own code wouldn't do that. Perhaps a if side_b = None and area = None would help

Comment: Never assume that the person using the code is the same person who wrote the code.

Comment: That sounds like good practice, actually. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Even if you are the one who uses the code that you wrote, its unlikely that you'll remember weird edge cases

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
class Combined:
    def __init__(self, a, b=None, area=None):
        self.a = a
        self.area = self.a * b if b else area
        self.b = self.area / self.a
```

Answer (score 0):

I would share a basic example to use default as well as parametrized constructor in python. You need to declare as well as assign variable in function definition itself for default constructor.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self,name="",age=0):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
    def __int__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def showdetails(self):
        print("\nName is "+str(self.name)+" and age is "+str(self.age))

p1=Person("Sam",50)

p1.showdetails()

p2=Person()

p2.showdetails()
```

Output:

```
Name is Sam and age is 50

Name is  and age is 0
```