# AttributeError: 'Team' object has no attribute 'jng_player'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
import csv
from hashlib import new
class Player:
   def __init__(self, row, header):
        self.__dict__ = dict(zip(header, row))
        
class Team:
  def __init__(self, top_player:Player, mid_player: Player, bot_player: Player, jng_player: Player, sup_player: Player, result: Player, team_id, game_id):
    self.top_player = top_player
    self.mid_player = mid_player
    self.bot_player = bot_player
    self.jng_player = jng_player
    self.sup_player = sup_player
    self.result = self.top_player.result
    self.team_id = self.top_player.team_id
    self.game_id = self.top_player.game_id
    
  def __init__(self) -> None:
      pass
        
class Game:

  def __init__(self, game_id, winnerTeam:Team, loserTeam:Team):
    self.game_id = game_id
    self.winnerTeam = winnerTeam
    self.loserTeam = loserTeam
    
  def __init__(self) -> None:
      pass
```

The Game and Player class works fine but the Team class shows up error when I tried to hit it with  print(game.winnerTeam.jng_player.dealths)

Comment: share full error trace and how you are invoking the functions

Comment: There are two __init__ in your Team class. You should remove second __init__function. There are no method overload in python.

Answer (score 0):

I believe second `__init__` in the `Team` class overwrites the first `__init__`, so basically `Team` is a class without any attributes. See also: [Multiple constructors in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820137/multiple-constructors-in-python).