# Instantiate without parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance

So im trying to use a method from another class but im having to add all the paramenters from the class im using the method from. is there anyway around this?

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       label = tk.Label(self, text = "aaaa")
       label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

       A = managers()
       method = getattr(A, printAll) ## "printAll" is the method im trying to get 

       addemployee = tk.Button(self, text = "Start", command = method)
       addemployee.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)



class managers(workers):

    def __init__(self, firstname, surname, age, postcode, wage, Employees = None):
        super().__init__(firstname, surname, age, postcode, wage)

    def printAll(self): #### the method i want to use
        for emp in self.employees:
            print(emp.Fullname(), "-", emp.Age(), "-", self.Postcode(), "-", self.Wage())
```

Comment: How will you use that method if you don't instantiate those attributes?

Comment: Also, what does your MainPage class have to do with this question?

Comment: @coldspeed i dont want to re-add the parameters as i have made an object with all the info at the botton of the class. `a = managers("Sha", "Jan", 21, "UB4 NM3", 1900000)`, as for the MainPage, it was just an example, i have not supplied all the code. Only the necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values so you don't have to pass everything.

```
class managers(workers):

def __init__(self, firstname="fname", surname="sname", age="196", postcode="pc", wage="1$", Employees = None):
```

The other option that allows you complete freedom, as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python) is to pass params using args and keyword args `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`