# Calling a class that is inside a function

Tags: python

Would it be possible to call a class that is inside of a function?

Example:

```
def func():
  class testclass:
    print("testclass")
```

How would i call testclass in a position like this?

Comment: You can call it only from inside the method

Comment: The class is redefined every time you call the function. You can't easily access the class from outside the function.

Comment: You can’t “call” a class. in the code you’ve shown you’re *defining* a class, and when you create objects from it you are *instantiating* it.

Comment: The same way you use *any* object created inside a function, you return it from the function and it is up to the caller to use the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def mymethod(value):
    class TestClass:
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
    t = TestClass(value)
    print(f"Inside method printing a value {t.a}")
    return t

test = mymethod(5)
print(f"Outside method printing object's value {test.a}")
```

Possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this; however python has several ways to build classes with different characteristics. Some strategies you may want to look into include inheritance or "mixins" and/or to have several constructor methods like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/6019407

I think this approach is generally considered more in keeping with the python style ("pythonic").