# Can I use two constructor methods in Python?

Tags: python, constructor

In Python, can I do something like the following that I did in Java?

I want to have two constructors, a default constructor and one that asks me to send a string.

```java
public class Person
{
   String name;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Person person = new Person("John");
      Person person2 = new Person();
   }

   public Person()
   {
     name = "No name";
   }

   public Person(String name)
   {
     this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you wouldn't overload the constructor, but give the `name` argument a default value:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="No Name"):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can't have multiple constructors. The only way is to use these elements:

- a keyword argument
- an optional argument with a default value

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="No name"):
        self.name = name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Person()
    p2 = Person("John")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without additional library help for faking overloaded functions. The Pythonic equivalent is to define *one* `__init__` method and an additional class method that uses `__init__`. For example,

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def nameless(cls, self):
        return cls("No name")

person = Person("Jhon")
person2 = Person.nameless()
```

though in this case, this is overkill for providing a default argument, which can be done with

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="No name"):
        self.name = name

person = Person("Jhon")
person2 = Person()
```