# How to have multiple inits for a class

Tags: python

I want to create a class called `Chain`.
I want to be able to call `__init__` method multiple times.
For example:

```
>> Chain(1)
1
>> Chain(1)(2)
3
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Implement `__call__` on your class. That's what will be executed if you use `()` on an instance of the class.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: You'll also need to override `__repr__` so that the first call produces `1`, rather than something like `<__main__.Chain object at 0x10c2a76d0>`

Comment: Implement `__call__` and  `__eq__`

Comment: And `__str__`/`__repr__` so it "looks like" the answer.

Comment: It can't return the first number and support chaining. You'll have to override `__eq__` to support comparing an instance of `Chain` to a different value.

Comment: Why implement your own `__eq__` and `__repr__` when `int` has perfectly good implementations of those already?  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do *exactly* what you have shown (the usefulness of which I question), you need to override `__repr__` and define `__call__`. For example,

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.x)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return Chain(self.x + x)
```

Since `__call__` returns a new instance of `Chain`, you can chain calls indefinitely.

```
>>> Chain(1)
1
>>> Chain(1)(2)
3
>>> Chain(1)(2)(3)
6
```

`Chain` itself will always return an instance of `Chain` (unless you define `Chain` using a metaclass other than the default of `type`). `Chain.__call__` is what allows you to call an instance of `Chain` like a function, returning a function to allow the actual chain of calls to continue. `__repr__` is used so that each attempt to "show" the instance produces the value of its attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You just need a callable `int`:

```
>>> class Chain(int):
...     def __call__(self, other: int) -> Chain:
...         return Chain(self + other)
...
>>> Chain(10) == 10
True
>>> Chain(1)(2)(3)
6
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this answer your question?

```py
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self, value):
        return Chain(self.value + value)


one = Chain(1)
three = Chain(1)(2)
print(three.value)
```

Just to explain what `__call__` does is:

> **call** is method enables Python programmers to write classes where the instances
> behave like functions and can be called like a function.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot implement multiple `__inits__` since it's the function which initializes variables etc.

What you can do is implement the `__call__` function, which is the one being called when you call an instance e.g

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        print("Init")
    def __call__(self,b):
        print("call")
        self.b=b

inst = MyClass(1) # "Init"
inst(2) #"call"
```