# Chaining calls to a class in Python

Tags: python

*This is from a past programming contest*

Implement a class *Chain* that when called a number of times in a chain with numeric inputs, returns the sum of them.

```
>>> Chain(1)(2)(3)
6
>>> Chain(10) == 10
True
```

The thing is that in the first example the first call should return a number (i.e. 1), which is not callable. So how can the chain continue evaluating?

Comment: Very similar, by the way, to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70621791/1126841

Comment: Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70621791/12416453)