# Setting instance variables in a factory method

Tags: python, oop

The problem in code:

```
class Object:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.a = some_logic(x)
    self.b = some_logic(y)

  @classmethod
  def produce_object(cls, x, y, additional_knowledge) -> 'Object':
    a = some_different_logic(x, additional_knowledge)
    b = some_different_logic(y, additional_knowledge)
    # now how to initialize Object?
    # bad ( I dont want to call some_logic):
    o = Object(x, y)
    o.a = x
    o.b = y
    return o
```

I want to create a new instance, that creates it in another way than the constructor does. For this alternative way I would maybe use some additional knowledge that allows me to call produce_object (which spares me a lot of expensive calculations located in the constructor).

In Java I would place the a and b instance variables outside the constructor in the body of the class.
If I do this in python, they are treated as static members.

Do i have to do something like this ?:

```
class Object:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = None
    self.b = None

  def former_constructor(self, x, y):
    self.a = some_logic(x)
    self.b = some_logic(y)
   
  def produce_object(self, x, y):
    self.a = some_different_logic(x)
    self.b = some_different_logic(y)
```

My best guess (since you cant have multiple constructors, right?) that one would write a very generic constructor. This of course leads to complicated code in the real world (imagine you have 3 ways to calculate your stuff. One takes arguments of type A and B, second C and D, third E and F. But you always have to provide everything (with potentially four Nones).

Any comment on this is very appreciatied. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Check **@Ber** answer to the question [What is a clean, Pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)

Comment: One answer illustrates how a classmethod from_x avoids calling the constructor. This is exactly what I need. Pity I cannot accept a comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `@classmethod` approach can be modified to provide an alternative
> constructor which does not invoke the default constructor (**init**).
> Instead, an instance is created using **new**.

According to [@Andrzej Pronobis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)

Comment: Makes it easier for others if you link directly to [Andrzej Pronobis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python/38885481#38885481)

Comment: Thanks, that was my intention, now understood how to do it.