# How would we create a class constructor which does nothing if the input is already an instance of that class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor

How would we create a class constructor which does nothing if the input is already an instance of that class?

The following code does not work, but it does partially show you what I am trying to accomplish:

```python
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self
        else:
            self._seeds = "".join(str(arg) for arg in args)
```

We probably have to override (overload?) `__new__`, or create a meta-class, but I am not sure how to do that.

The class named `Apple` was very contrived.

In the big picture, I am trying to write a function which can accept either parsed or un-parsed data as input.

If the data is already parsed, there is no reason to parse it a second time.

If the input is an instance of `ParsedData`, then we return the input.

If the input is not an instance of `ParsedData` then we pass the input into the constructor of the class named `ParsedData`.

Comment: Put the logic in a method instead of the constructor. Then only call the constructor if needed.

Comment: E.g. a classmethod, `Apple.from_maybe_apple(unknown_thing)`. That's the convention for alternative constructors, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/3001761. But it's unclear how any of that relates to the _function_ you're describing, why is what you've put in `__init__` not just in that function?

Comment: btw your `__init__` method cannot work how you would like. It will produce this error: `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Apple'`

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the logic in a function:

```
def parse_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, ParsedData):
        return data
    return ParsedData(data)
```

or as others have suggested, you can use a classmethod

```
class ParsedData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, cls):
            return data
        return cls(data)  


parsed = ParsedData.from_data(my_data)
```