# Chaining classmethod constructors

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, class-method

[There is an idiom in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/857932) to use classmethods to provide additional ways to construct an object, where the conversion/transformation logic stays in the classmethod and the `__init__()` exists solely to initialize the fields. For example:

```py
class Foo:
  field1: bytes

  def __init__(self, field1: bytes):
    self.field1 = field1

  @classmethod
  def from_hex(cls, hex: str) -> Foo:
    '''
    construct a Foo from a hex string like "12:34:56:78"
    '''
    return cls(field1=bytes.fromhex(hex.replace(':', ' ')))
```

Now, let's say I define a class derived from Foo:

```py
class Bar(Foo):
  field2: str

  def __init__(self, field1: bytes, field2: str):
    Foo.__init__(self, field1)
    self.field2 = field2
```

With this hierarchy in mind, I want to define a constructor `Bar.from_hex_with_tag()` that would serve as an extension of `Foo.from_hex()`:

```py
class Bar(Foo):
  <...>

  @classmethod
  def from_hex_with_tag(cls, hex: str, tag: str) -> Bar:
    return cls(
      field1=bytes.fromhex(hex.replace(':', ' ')),  # duplicated code with Foo.from_hex()
      field2=tag
    )
```

---

How do I reuse `Foo.from_hex()` in `Bar.from_hex_with_tag()`?

Comment: There's not really much to reuse from `Foo.from_hex` in its current form. You'd need to externalise the parts you want to reuse into other functions. Or you'd need to allow passing through of additional arguments with `*args`/`**kwargs`. What the _best_ solution is will very much depend on a case by case basis. For a trivial case like this, just repeating the code as you do may be the optimal solution already. You'd need to have more complex and substantial code to warrant the additional complexity of taking it apart more.

Comment: Well, the current form is a minimal example. Let's assume that there is enough logic in there to warrant reuse.

Comment: Adding to @deceze, reusing `classmethod`s like this relies on everything adhering to the Liskov Substitution Principle. Your subclass doesn't adhere to it (its initializer requires an extra argument), so the best you can do is factor out the type-conversion code in the parent (likely as an underscore-prefixed `@staticmethod` utility) so both the parent and the child can use it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Constructors (including alternative constructors like class methods) aren't really included in the LSP. Otherwise it would be very hard to make subclasses usefully different in any way. Only the instance interface needs to be substitutable.

Comment: @deceze: Yeah, it's a little weird there, but in practice, if the two `__init__`s have incompatible signatures, `@classmethod`s can't be used by inherited classes, for roughly the same reasons adhering to LSP is encouraged; the parent class wrote the `classmethod` to match the signature of its `__init__`, so if the child class *requires* a different number of arguments (or the meaning of the arguments changes), the `@classmethod` would have to be overridden on the child class to make it functional.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing `classmethod`s like this relies on everything adhering to [the Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Your subclass doesn't adhere to it (its initializer requires an extra argument), so the best you can do is factor out the type-conversion code in the parent (likely as an underscore-prefixed `@staticmethod` utility) so both the parent and the child can use it.

For example, you might do:

```
class Foo:
  field1: bytes

  def __init__(self, field1: bytes):
    self.field1 = field1

  @staticmethod
  def _field_from_hex(hex: str) -> bytes:
      return bytes.fromhex(hex.replace(':', ' '))

  @classmethod
  def from_hex(cls, hex: str) -> Foo:
    '''
    construct a Foo from a hex string like "12:34:56:78"
    '''
    return cls(field1=cls._field_from_hex(hex))
```

so `Bar` can be:

```
class Bar(Foo):
  <...>

  @classmethod
  def from_hex_with_tag(cls, hex: str, tag: str) -> Bar:
    return cls(
      field1=cls._field_from_hex(hex),
      field2=tag
    )
```

If the `__init__` for `Bar` can make the `field2` argument *optional* (so the parent `classmethod` is valid), you could make this work like so:

```
class Bar(Foo):
  def __init__(self, field1: bytes, field2: str = ''):
    super().__init__(field1)
    self.field2 = field2

  @classmethod
  def from_hex_with_tag(cls, hex: str, tag: str) -> Bar:
    self = cls.from_hex(hex)
    self.field2 = tag
    return self
```

where you just have a placeholder at construction time which you then manually replace after, but that would also allow users of your class to construct without the second argument, which may be undesirable.