# How to restrict instances of a class from accessing certain methods?

Tags: python, class

I currently have a class that has several attributes and methods. I want to implement a pseudo alternative constructor for a special case initialization. I plan to use the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545.

Here's a skeleton of what I want to do:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, input1, input2....)
    # init the class
  @classmethod
  def alt_ctor(cls, input):
    return cls...

  def method1(self):
    # do something

  def method2(self):
    # do something

  def method3(self):
    # do something
```

For instances created using `alt_ctor`, I only want to give it access to `method2` and no access to other methods.

Is there a simple way to do this in Python? The only way I know is to have some flag that's read in by `alt_ctor` and stored as an instance attribute, and then assert against that flag for each of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should have two separate classes, not one class with alternative constructors:

```
class MyClassLimited:
    def __init__(self, input):
        # ...

    def method2(self):
        # ...

class MyClass(MyClassLimited):
    def __init__(self, input1, input2, input3):
        input = # ...
        super().__init__(input)
        # ...

    def method1(self):
        # ...

    def method3(self):
        # ...
```