# Constructor overloading in python with default arguments

Tags: python, class, constructor-overloading

I defined a class in python as following.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,edate,fdate=""):
        print("Constructors with default arguments...")

    def __init__(self):
        print("Default Constructor")
```

I created an object for this class,

```
obj = myclass()
```

It works fine. And I expected the following object creation will work,

```
obj1 = myclass("01-Feb-2019")
```

But It throws an error saying,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 9, in <module>
    obj = myclass("01-Feb-2019")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

But If I change the definition of the class as follows,

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Default Constructor")
    def __init__(self,edate,fdate=""):
        print("Constructors with default arguments...")
```

Now `obj1 = myclass("01-Feb-2019")` works. But `obj = myclass()` throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 10, in <module>
    obj = myclass()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'edate'
```

Could we define a constructor overloading in Python? Could I define a constructor which accepts the empty argument as well as one argument?

Comment: Have you looked at how Python stores an object's methods and properties? This behavior will make sense if you do.

Comment: Within your class you define two methods with the same name `__init__`. Whichever is the second is what you end up with and respectively - what arguments are expected or not.

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, Python does not support multiple constructors *). However you can emulate them easily as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, edate=None, fdate=""):
        if edate:
            print("Constructors with default arguments...")
        else:
            print("Default Constructor")
```

Then you can do

```
obj1 = MyClass("01-Feb-2019")
=> Constructors with default arguments...
obj2 = MyClass()
=> Default Constructor
```

*) except if you go for [multi-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49936625/890242) - making use of Python's powerful inspection features

Note that assigning default values in the method declaration should be done very reluctantly as it may [work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) than one thinks coming from another language. The proper way to define default values would be using 
`None` and assign default values like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, edate=None, fdate=None):
        if edate:
           fdate = "" if fdate is None else fdate
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike **Java or C#**, you cannot define multiple constructors. However, you can define a **default value** if one is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have multiple constructors - see [Multiple constructors in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164258/multiple-constructors-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `multipledispatch`([link](https://multiple-dispatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/design.html)) module to overload methods

### Installation:

```
python3 -m pip install multipledispatch
```

> A Dispatcher object stores and selects between different
> implementations of the same abstract operation. It selects the
> appropriate implementation based on a signature, or list of types. We
> build one dispatcher per abstract operation.
>
> The [**dispatch**](https://multiple-dispatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/design.html#namespaces-and-dispatch) decorator hides the creation and manipulation of
> Dispatcher objects from the user.

Using @dispatch wrapper to overload methods:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch


class Shape:
    @dispatch(int)
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.dimension = 1

    @dispatch(float)
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.dimension = 1

    @dispatch(int, int)
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.dimension = 2
        self._getArea = lambda: self.length * self.width

    @dispatch(float, float)
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.dimension = 2
        self._getArea = lambda: self.length * self.width

    @dispatch(int, int, int)
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.dimension = 3
        self._getArea = lambda: 2 * (self.length * self.width + self.length * self.height +
                                     self.width * self.height)
        self._getVolume = lambda: self.length * self.width * self.height

    @dispatch(float, float, float)
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.dimension = 3
        self._getArea = lambda: 2 * (self.length * self.width + self.length * self.height +
                                     self.width * self.height)
        self._getVolume = lambda: self.length * self.width * self.height

    def getLength(self):
        return self.length

    def getArea(self):
        if self.dimension == 1:
            raise Exception(f"Shapes with {self.dimension} dimensions have no area")
        return self._getArea()

    def getVolume(self):
        if self.dimension < 3:
            raise Exception(f"Shapes with {self.dimension} dimensions have no volume")
        return self._getVolume()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = Shape(3)
    curve = Shape(5.5)
    rectangle = Shape(5.5, 100.1)
    cuboid = Shape(23, 22, 10)

    print(line.getLength())
    print(curve.getLength())
    print(rectangle.getArea())
    print(cuboid.getVolume(), cuboid.getArea())
    
    #will raise Exception since rectangles don't have volume
    print(rectangle.getVolume())
```

### Output:

```
3
5.5
550.55
5060 1912
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
  Exception: Shapes with 2 dimensions have no volume
```