# Is it good form to have an __init__ method that checks the type of its input?

Tags: python

I have a class that wants to be initialized from a few possible inputs. However a combination of no function overloading and my relative inexperience with the language makes me unsure of how to proceed. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/overloading-init-in-python) asked earlier.

In short, the recommendation is that you use [classmethods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) or `isinstance()`, with classmethods being heavily favored.

Comment: Thomas Wouter's accepted answer on that link is really good (and much better than a blind suggestion to use duck-typing) but as it stands, I think that your answer should have been a comment. Maybe you should add some more info, for example, mentioning the use of class methods for this sort of thing.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Thanks, I'm still picking up what proper SO etiquette is in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

With Python, you should use duck typing. Wikipedia has a good section on its use in Python at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what others have answered, it's not rare to check for types in `__init__`.  For example the [`array.array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array) class in the Python Standard library accepts an optional `initializer` argument, which may be a list, string, or iterable.  The documentation explicitly states different actions take place *based on the type.*  For another example of the same treatment *by argument type* see [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal).  Or see [`zipfile.Zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects), which accepts a `file` argument "where file can be either a path to a file (a string) or a file-like object."  (Here we see both explicit type checking (a string) and duck typing (a file-like object) all in one!)

If you find explicit type checking in `__init__` is getting messy, try a different approach.  Use factory functions instead.  For example, let's say you have a `triangle` module with a `Triangle` class.  There are many ways to construct a triangle.  Rather than having `__init__` handle all these ways, you could add factory methods to your module:

- `triangle.from_sas(side1, angle, side2)`
- `triangle.from_asa(angle1, side, angle2)`
- `triangle.from_sss(side1, side2, side3)`
- `triangle.from_aas(angle1, angle2, side)`

These factory methods could also be rolled into the `Triangle` class, using the `@classmethod` decorator.  For an excellent example of this technique see Thomas Wouter's fine answer to stackoverflow question [overloading **init** in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/overloading-init-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

No, don't check for types explicitly. Python is a duck typed language. If the wrong type is passed, a `TypeError` will be raised. That's it. You need not bother about the type, that is the responsibility of the programmer.