# Difference between 'cls' and 'self' in Python classes?

Tags: python, class, object, terminology, self

Why is `cls` sometimes used instead of `self` as an argument in Python classes?

For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    @classmethod
    def from_fullname(cls, fullname):
        cls.firstname, cls.lastname = fullname.split(' ', 1)
```

Answer (score 425):

The distinction between `"self"` and `"cls"` is defined in [`PEP 8`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) . As Adrien said, this is not mandatory. It's a coding style. `PEP 8` says:

> *Function and method arguments*:
>
> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use `cls` for the first argument to class methods.

Comment: Can you please help suggest how the difference is "coding style" while [abdilatiBashir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221349/3755989) answers the difference is of class-versus-instance? Do you disagree with him?

Answer (score 137):

`cls` implies that method belongs to the class while self implies that the  method is related to instance of the class,therefore member with `cls` is accessed by class name where as the one with self is accessed by instance of the class...it is the same concept as `static member` and `non-static members` in java if you are from java background.

Comment: Thank you for the Java reference, now understand.

Comment: Than you for the mentioning `static member` and `non-static members`, understood it in context of c++

Answer (score 64):

It's used in case of a class method. Check [this reference](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) for further details.

EDIT: As clarified by Adrien, it's a convention. You can actually use anything but `cls` and `self` are used (**PEP8**).

Answer (score 34):

This is very good question but not as wanting as question.
There is difference between 'self' and 'cls' used method though analogically they are at same place

```
def moon(self, moon_name):
    self.MName = moon_name

#but here cls method its use is different 

@classmethod
def moon(cls, moon_name):
    instance = cls()
    instance.MName = moon_name
```

Now you can see both are moon function but one can be used inside class while other function name moon can be used for any class.

For practical programming approach :

While designing circle class we use **area** method as cls instead of self because we don't want area to be limited to particular class of circle only .

Comment: if you like to add something more which coders looking for,if right,will approve it.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to access a method via instance, keep first parameter as self. For example:

```
class Test:
   def hello(self, name):
      print ('hello ', name)

obj = Test()
obj.hello('Rahul')
```

If you want to access method using class name like we do in static class, better you use cls as first parameter in method. For example:

```
class Test:
       def hello(cls, name):
          print ('hello ', name)


Test.hello('Rahul')
```

Comment: Works with 'x = Test()' and 'x.hello('Rahul')'.

Comment: What python version is that? The second block of code doesn't work, unless the @classmethod decorator is provided.

Comment: **DOES NOT APPLY TO:** python2 and python3. it is function decorator `@classvariable` that feeds the [class as an implicit first argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Answer (score 12):

> Instead of accepting a self parameter, class methods take a **cls** parameter that points to the **class**—and not the **object instance**—when
>   the method is called.
>   Since the class method only has access to this cls argument, **it can’t
>   modify object instance state**. That would require access to self . However, class methods can still modify class state that applies across all
>   instances of the class.

-*Python Tricks*

Answer (score 1):

This code snip demonstrates difference between `class` method and `instance` method.

The use of variable name `(lol ,` is valid.

Note: variable name `(self ,` and `(cls,`  are *style* **NOT** *syntax* [answered Jan 25, 2011, Baskaya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795306/6345724)

```
class Parent:
    greeting = 'Good morning'
    name = 'Mum'
    def greet(lol):
        return lol.greeting
    def who_am_i(lol):
        return 'i am ' + lol.name

class Child(Parent):
    greeting = 'mate'
    @classmethod
    def greet(lol):
        return lol.greeting

>>> p = Parent()
>>> print(p.greet(), p.who_am_i() )
'Good morning i am Mum'
>>> c = Child()
>>> print(c.greet(), c.who_am_i() )
'mate i am Mum'
```