# What are built-in identifiers in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was reading [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) and came across this line which I couldn't understand:

> Standard exception names are built-in identifiers (not reserved
>   keywords).

What is meant by `built-in identifiers`? I know there are built-in functions like `open()`,i.e., functions which we don't need to import.

Comment: The standard exceptions are part of the ```builtin```'s their names are just identifiers, NOT keywords. try ```import builtins; for identifier in dir(builtins):  print(identifier)```.  It should print the name/identifierfor each of the *built-in* Exceptions plus other built-ins.

Comment: @wwii these are by far not all identifiers python knows, for example `cls` is missing, `__new__`, `__init__` etc.

Comment: @defoe is `cls` a builtin identifier or a convention that is used as a name for a class object? If you assign a string to the name `cls` will you be shadowing an identifier that Python itself uses? ...  [What is the 'cls' variable used for in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-for-in-python-classes)

Comment: Yes, `cls` does not seem to be a builtin identifier, but `__init__` and `__new__` should be.

Comment: I just commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/2823755) wondering about special method names.

Comment: [2.3.2. Reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)

Answer (score 4):

It is exactly what you think it is, a name of a thing which isn't a function, and isn't a command like "while", and comes built-in to Python. e.g.

A function is something like `open()`, a keyword is something like `while` and an identifier is something like `True`, or `IOError`.

More of them:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 
'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis',
 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 
'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 
'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 
'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 
'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 
'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 
'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 
'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 
'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 
'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'WindowsError', 'ZeroDivisionError', 
'_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 
'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 
'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 
'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 
'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 
'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 
'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 
'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 
'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 
'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 
'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 
'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

Documentation backup:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

> 5.2. Atoms
>   Atoms are the most basic elements of expressions. The simplest atoms are identifiers or literals
>
> An identifier occurring as an atom is a name

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

> Identifiers (also referred to as names)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, an identifier is the name given to a particular entity, be it a class, variable, function etc. For example, when I write:

```
some_variable = 2
try:
    x = 6 / (some_variable - 2)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    x = None
```

both `some_variable` and `x` are identifiers that I have defined. The third identifier here is the `ZeroDivisionError` exception, which is a **built-in** identifier (that is, you don't have to import it or define it before you can use it).

This is contrasted with **reserved keywords**, which don't identify an object, but rather help define the Python language itself. These include `import`, `for`, `while`, `try`, `except`, `if`, `else`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers are 'variable names'. Built-ins are, well, built-in objects that come with Python and don't need to be imported. They are associated with identifiers in the same way we can associate 5 with `foo` by saying `foo = 5`.

Keywords are special tokens like `def`. Identifiers cannot be keywords; keywords are 'reserved'.

For built-in keywords like `open`, though, you *can* use identifiers with the same spelling. So you can say `open = lambda: None` and you have overrided or 'shadowed' the built-in previously associated with the name `open`. It's generally not a good idea to shadow built-ins as it warms readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the builtins using following command ...

```
dir(__builtins__)
```

it will give following output

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'RecursionError', 'ReferenceError', 'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopAsyncIteration', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '__build_class__', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

then if you want to check what can we do with these builtins following will give you the definition `help("<name_of_the_builin_function>")`

```
>>> help("zip")
Help on class zip in module builtins:

class zip(object)
 |  zip(iter1 [,iter2 [...]]) --> zip object
 |  
 |  Return a zip object whose .__next__() method returns a tuple where
 |  the i-th element comes from the i-th iterable argument.  The .__next__()
 |  method continues until the shortest iterable in the argument sequence
 |  is exhausted and then it raises StopIteration.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __getattribute__(self, name, /)
 |      Return getattr(self, name).
 |  
 |  __iter__(self, /)
 |      Implement iter(self).
 |  
 |  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
 |      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  __next__(self, /)
 |      Implement next(self).
 |  
 |  __reduce__(...)
 |      Return state information for pickling.
```