# calling super class init when child class is created using type()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class dynamically using the python type() method.

So, say i have a base class 'A'

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am in init of A..")
```

Now i create a child class 'C' by using type method

```
>>> C = type('C',(A,),{})
```

When i create an object

```
>>> c = C()
I am in init of A..
```

The init of base class is also called correctly..

now i want to do something in my init method and i write a custom init method..

```
>>> def BsInit(self):
    print ("I am in init of B..")
```

and i create a class 'B' and create an instance..

```
>>> B = type('B',(A,),{'__init__':BsInit})
>>> b = B()
I am in init of B..
```

**The init of class A is not called at all..**

So tried to modify BsInit method like this:

```
>>> def BsInit(self):
    super().__init__();
    print ("I am in init of B..")
```

And i get the below error when i create an instance...

```
>>> B = type('B',(A,),{'__init__':BsInit})
>>> b = B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    b = B()
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 2, in BsInit
    super().__init__();print ("I am in init of B..")
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

All the examples i find with custom init using type() are really simple, like just initialising a variable.. but if i want to call base class Init too how to do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call it like so: `super(B, self).__init__()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass cls in init method instead of self. Below is the solution of your problem:

```
def init(cls):
    super(type(cls), cls).__init__()

B = type('B',(A,),{'__init__':init})
b = B()
"I am in init of A.."
```

Comment: I think cls ans self  are both same in this context.. the difference between cls and self is just a coding convention:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-in-python-classes

so  the below one too works:
def BsInit(self):
 super(type(self),self).__init__();
 print ("I am in init of B..")