# Using self vs cls to access variable in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, self, class-method

Lets say I have a simple class object that looks like some sort of `Counter` (of course it has other functions but it's out of scope for this question):

```
from collections import Counter

class Vocabulary:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.vocab = Counter(words)
```

And adding the `Vocabulary` class to a unittest, I could have use the `setUpClass` classmethod as such:

```
import unittest

class VocabularyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.vocab = Vocabulary(["z", "a", "b", "c", "f", "d", "e", "g", "a", "d", "b", "e", "w"])


    def test_counts_set_correctly(self):
        self.assertEqual(cls.vocab["a"], 2)
```

Or I could have just use `self`:

```
class VocabularyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VocabularyTests, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.vocab = Vocabulary(["z", "a", "b", "c", "f", "d", "e", "g", "a", "d", "b", "e", "w"])

    def test_counts_set_correctly(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.vocab["a"], 2)
```

And both of the above would work fine. But what if I've a sort of unpythonic pattern:

```
import unittest

class VocabularyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.vocab = Vocabulary(["z", "a", "b", "c", "f", "d", "e", "g", "a", "d", "b", "e", "w"])


    def test_counts_set_correctly(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.vocab["a"], 2)
```

According to [What is the 'cls' variable used for in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-for-in-python-classes), it's just a coding convention but is there any difference between the 3rd version of the unittest with `@classmethod` with the usage of `self.vocab` and the first two more idiomatic tests?

Comment: The first and third ones are the same, the second is different.

Comment: The first one would make a `NameError`, because from within `test_counts_set_correctly` the name `cls` would not be bound, far as I can tell.

Comment: @wim oh, didn't notice that. Yes, that would fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `unittest.TestCase` subclasses, **don't do any test setup in `__init__`**.  That's not what it's for. If you want the setup to be executed once-per test *method*, put it here:

```
def setUp(self):
    ...
```

If you want setup to be executed once per test *class*, put it here:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```

Finally let's address a misconception.  There is technically no difference between this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```

And this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(self):
    ...
```

The second one is just a more confusing/bad way of writing the first.