# Usage of ''self'' and ''cls'' in Python

Tags: python, class, class-method

I understand from the question [Difference between 'cls' and 'self' in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/difference-between-cls-and-self-in-python-classes) that `cls` is used in class methods while `self` is used in instance methods.

However, I used `self` in class methods and it is still working fine.

For example,

```
class Test:
  
  @classmethod
  def hello(self, name):
    print ('hello '+name)

Test.hello('Tom')
```

What exactly does `cls` or `self` do in class methods?

Comment: Well, it's just a naming convention!

Comment: Neither `self` nor `cls` is a language keyword or reserved word. You can call it `me` or `whatsyourname` or whatever you want. But as strongly as anything can be urged it is suggested to follow the convention.

Comment: Note that the convention is strong enough in the Python community that your text editor might color-code `self` differently. This leads a lot of people to think it's a keyword, but it's really just an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any name you want. But as per the naming [standard defined within PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)(Style Guide for Python Code), it's better to name `self` for the first argument to instance methods and `cls` for the first argument to class methods.

> **Function and Method Arguments**
>
> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use `cls` for the first argument to class methods.