# Class constructor able to init with an instance of the same class object

Tags: python, class, init, self

Can python create a class that can be initialised with an instance of the same class object?

I've tried this:

```
class Class(): 

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        print self

        self = kwargs.get('obj',self)

        print self

        if not hasattr(self,'attr1'):
            print 'attr1'
            self.attr1  = kwargs.pop('attr1',[])
        if not hasattr(self,'attr2'):
            print 'attr2'
            self.attr2 = kwargs.pop('attr2',[])

        print self

        self.attr1 = kwargs.pop('attr1',self.attr1)
        self.attr2 = kwargs.pop('attr2',self.attr2)
        print self.attr1
        print self.attr2
```

If I create a new instance there is no problem:

```
inst = Class(attr1=[1,2,3])
print inst
print inst.attr1,inst.attr2
```

The output is:

```
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025834cf8>  
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025834cf8>  
attr1  
attr2  
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025834cf8>  
[1, 2, 3]  
[]  
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025834cf8>  
[1, 2, 3]  []
```

But if I create a new instance with the instance `inst`:

```
inst2 = Class(obj=inst)
print inst2
print inst2.attr1,inst2.attr2
```

The output is:

```
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f202584b7e8>  
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025835830>  
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7f2025835830>  
[1, 2, 3]  
[]  
 <__main__.Class instance at 0x7f202584b7e8>
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-228-29c9869a9f4d> in <module>()  
       1 inst2 = Class(obj=inst)  
       2 print inst2  
 ----> 3 print inst2.attr1,inst2.attr2  

 AttributeError: Class instance has no attribute 'attr1'
```

I handle the problem but i dont know how to solve it:

- in the 1st case the instance address is always the same ("inside" and "outside" the class)
- in the 2nd case:

  - "inside" the class:
  - the init call create a new instance at a new address
  - then self is set to the previous instance and change address: OK
  - `self` already has attributes `attr1` and `atrr2` : OK
  - but "outside" the class:
  - `inst2` has the address from the init and has no attributes!

What is wrong ? How does address affectation work in Python?
Is it a good manner of doing this?

Comment: What? What are you actually trying to *achieve*?!

Comment: Imagine if you get this working. What will the syntax look like? How will you explain to others how to use your code?

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous and don't require comments (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/3001761). Not to mention that you **have had** a comment! If you can't be more explicit, then don't expect an answer. What are you actually trying to do? Implement a weird copying method via `__init__`? Why?

Comment: And what is *"address affectation"*?

Comment: @PeterWood This syntax will permit to a second instance to inherite of all attributes of a first instance except the ones that are re-initialize

Comment: @G.S **edit the question** to clarify what you're trying to achieve. Why not a `from_existing_instance` class method, rather than complicating the `__init__`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I say i cant be more explicit because i wrote my whole procedure! _Implement a weird copying method via __init__? Why?_ I say in my question that there is maybe a better/right manner, so can you explain whats this is the same of a copying method and how to do this

Comment: @G.S but your *"whole procedure"* neither works nor makes much sense. Either give a [mcve], a prose clear explanation, or (preferably) both. Maybe you want something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/19305296/3001761?

Comment: My example works I dont write the output by myself! If it doest make sense explain why ! Even I implement a `from_existing_instance` method i will have the same problem (except if i peel all the attributes of the existing instance). I see your proposed link, and it not correspond of what i m doing because it use inheritance

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for formatiing and you were right the example dont work because i change object to obj

Comment: You don't have to use inheritance, my point is that the canonical way to implement alternate constructors in Python is with a `@classmethod`. This feels like arguing with a wall, so I won't comment further.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont know a lot of wall that answers and takes in considerations arguments from others, I just want to be clear about what you say and what im answering.. Thanks for your help i will see the `@classmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but technically your error is here:

```
    self = kwargs.get('object',self)
```

There's nothing magic with `self`, it's just a function argument, and as such a local variable,  so rebinding it within the function will only make the local name `self` points to another object *within the function's scope*. It's in no way affecting the current instance (the one that was passed to `__init__` by the method wrapper), it just makes `self` an alias for `object`.

If what you want is to copy attributes from `object` to `self`, you have to do it explicitly:

```
 other = kwargs.get('object')
 if other is not None:
     self.attrx = other.attrx
     self.attry = other.attry
     # etc
```

Oh and yes: Python is high-level language, there's nothing like "address affectation" - all you have are names refering to objects (really, name=>object mapping). A name is just a name, and where the object actually lives is none of your concerns.

Comment: So if i understand well, self it just local variable which is an alias of the current instance (passed to _init_ by the method wrapper) ? and so if i rebinding it i "lose" the current instance within the _init_ scope ? @bruno\ desthuiliers

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score -1):

- Thanks to the comments above I understand 2 things:

  - `self` is just a local variable and it s not the class instance
  - `_init_` it s an class built-in method for initialize the instance from other object
- So if I want to be able to initialize a new class instance from an existing instance, I have just to create an "initializer" method which call the `_init_`:

  ```
  class Class(): 


      def __init__(self,**kwargs):

          self.attr1 = kwargs.pop('attr1',[])
          self.attr2 = kwargs.pop('attr2',[])

      def Class(self,**kwargs):

          return Class(attr1 = kwargs.pop('attr1',self.attr1),\
                       attr2 = kwargs.pop('attr2',self.attr2))
  ```

---

And use it like this:

```
inst = Class(attr1=[1,2,3])
print inst
print inst.attr1,inst.attr2
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7eff842d5368>
[1, 2, 3] []
```

---

```
inst2 = inst.Class(attr2=[12,11])
print inst2
print inst2.attr1,inst2.attr2
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Class instance at 0x7eff842d56c8>
[1, 2, 3] [12, 11]
```

Comment: "self is just a local variable and it s not the class instance" : `self` is a name in the function's scope, and this name initially refers to the current instance (the one on which the method has been called).